# Convergent Sequence Terminology

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the following sequence classified as?  I don't want to make anybody solve it, I just need to know where to begin looking to solve it.
$$\alpha_1 = \sqrt{20}$$
$$\alpha_{n+1} = \sqrt{20 + \alpha_n}$$

I am suppose to prove that it converges to 5, however if I could just get a little terminology help it is more then appreciated!

Note: I updated the terminology, as well as give the initial value.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a "recursively defined" **sequence**, not a series. And for this to make sense, you need to give a *starting value* ($\alpha_1$, or $\alpha_n$).

Comment: The word "moron" is excessive. People are not always familiar with the correct mathematical terminology. The important thing is that you fixed the mistake.

Comment: We all make mistakes; it is good that you now have rectified your post, and so there is no need to beat yourself up for your previous mistake.

Comment: @Asaf: It sure is! :-)

Comment: Moron: Don't be an ass. ;-)

Comment: Related, but contains spoilers (so don't read it just yet): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11945/limit-of-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-cdots/11969#11969

Comment: @Asaf : Ass you say :-)

Comment: I am glad the math people have a good sense of humor :)  I just know it is really annoying when n00b's make stupid mistakes and you have to write a really long message to explain why (I am not great with math, but give me software to write, and I am told I am less n00bish :).  Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<strike>First, it's not a series, it's a **sequence**.</strike>  Fixed in the original.

Second, it's  a *recursively defined* sequence.

A sequence is "recursively defined" if you specify some specific values and then you explain how to get the "next value" from the previous one; much like induction. Here, you are saying how to get the "next term", $\alpha_{n+1}$, if you already know the value of the $n$th term, $\alpha_n$.

Once you know the *first value*, then the sequence is completely determined by that first value and the "recurrence rule" $\alpha_{n+1}=\sqrt{20+\alpha_n}$.

Now some hints:

- Show the sequence is increasing.
- Show the sequence is bounded.
- Conclude the sequence converges.
- Once you know it converges, take limits on both sides of the recursion to try to figure out *what* it converges to.

Comment: I apologize about that, I updated the original post.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent hinting of Arturo, I say that it might be useful to consider the intuitively-inappropriate statement that $ x = \sqrt{20 + x} $, or rather that $x^2 = 20 + x$.

To be clear, the existence of a solution to this statement does not imply the existence of a solution to your recurrence, but after following Arturo's hints...

Good luck!