# Does $A_n= \sqrt{1^2+\sqrt{2^2+\sqrt{...+\sqrt{n^2}}}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, nested-radicals

Can we find the value of $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} A_n$, does it converge?

$$A_n= \sqrt{1^2+\sqrt{2^2+\sqrt{3^2+\sqrt{4^2+\sqrt{...+\sqrt{n^2}}}}}} $$

I tried to calculate $A_1,A_2,\cdots A_{10}$, but my computer cannot do further terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61055/86940) for references to a criterion.
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log n^2}{2^n} = 2\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log n}{2^n} = 0$$
So the convergence is positive. The value is another story though.

Comment: Can we find the vaule?

Comment: The value can be found by bijection.
Take $x_1$ as a suitable approximation of the limit and define:
$$x_n = x_{n-1}^2 - (n-1)^2.$$
If, soon or later, $x_n\geq n+2$, then $x_1$ is an approximation from above of the limit, because we have $x_N\geq N+2$ for any $N\geq n$. Otherwise, if $x_m\leq m+1$ happens, $x_1$ is an approximation from below, because we have $x_{m+1}<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, we can do a numeric approximation. I used the following code (Mathematica):

```
N[Module[{n = 0}, 
         Nest[(n++; # /. x -> n^2 + Sqrt[x]) &, 
              Sqrt[x], 50]
  ] /. x -> 0,
  50]
```

which first recursively puts an $x$ inside the $51$st radical, then replaces it by zero, and approximates the result to $50$ digits.

This gives the number:

$$A_{50} \approx 1.9426554227639873282214132914126672376880736300071$$

The above code can easily be executed for deeper nested radicals to obtain more precision, but the first $50$ digits are correct.

The [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard) does not have any suggestions for the limit -- not even in "advanced" mode. So it may just be your average irrational number outside of $\mathsf{Alg}(\Bbb Q[\pi,e])$, the numbers algebraic over $\Bbb Q[\pi,e]$.