# Infinitely Nested Radical with Fibonacci Coefficients

Tags: radicals, fibonacci-numbers, nested-radicals

I was wondering if the following infinitely nested radical can be evaluated.

$$x= \sqrt{1+ \color{red}{1}\sqrt{1+ \color{red}{1}\sqrt{1+ \color{red}{2}\sqrt{1+ \color{red}{3}\sqrt{1+ \color{red}{5}\sqrt{1+ \dots }}}}}} \,= \,??$$

with coefficients being the Fibonacci numbers. Generally, is there a way to evaluate all infinitely nested radicals with coefficients being the terms of a fibonacci-like sequence?

Thank you!

Comment: I have seen a solution on this site. Start [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61048/definition-of-convergence-of-a-nested-radical-sqrta-1-sqrta-2-sqrta-3?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61012/nested-square-roots-50-sqrt51-sqrt52-sqrt54-sqrt-dots?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/evaluating-the-nested-radical-sqrt1-2-sqrt1-3-sqrt1-cdots) from Ramanujan's note book...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating the nested radical $ \sqrt{1 + 2 \sqrt{1 + 3 \sqrt{1 + \cdots}}} $.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/evaluating-the-nested-radical-sqrt1-2-sqrt1-3-sqrt1-cdots)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't think Ramanujan considered this case. Ramanujan's "coefficients" for his famous nested radical were $2,3,4,\dots$, while Altun used the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Can anyone find the value of $x$ to 10 or more digits?