# Basic Sequence Proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given these condition, I am seeking a proof:

Define a sequence of real numbers by $x_1 = 3$ and then, for $n \geq 2$,

$x_n = \sqrt{2 \; x_{n-1} + 1 }$

Prove that for all positive integers $n$, $x_n \geq x_{n+1}$.

I began a proof by induction, but ran out of steam. I tested the base case for $n=2$ , but I could not seem to get anywhere after that. I feel like there is not enough information (ie recursion, sequence, etc) to prove by induction. Is an induction proof an efficient way to proceed? Are there easier methods of proof?

Comment: If you basically prove $x_n >= \sqrt{2}+1$ and $x_n >= \sqrt{2}-1$ for every $n$,  you are done

Comment: @Kirthi Raman : You should learn how to use LaTeX coding properly. Use \le to type $\le$ when you are between cash symbols (math mode).

Comment: Set $x_n  = 2y_n$ and you get it in the form $y_{n+1} = \sqrt{y_n + c}$. Which is a dupe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [On the sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+x_n}$ ](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/on-the-sequence-x-n1-sqrtcx-n)

Comment: Thank you Patrick, I have to learn many more things and latex is sure in my list

Comment: Aryabhata is a veteran here, it is indeed a duplicate.I have been on this group only past 23 days and have to learn every day. (I am his fan!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the induction, assume that $x_n\leq x_{n-1}$.  Then

$$
\begin{align*}
x_n &\leq x_{n-1}\\
2x_n &\leq 2x_{n-1}\\
2x_n+1 &\leq 2x_{n-1}+1\\
\sqrt{2x_n+1} &\leq \sqrt{2x_{n-1}+1}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: can I simply make that assumption though? Wouldn't a typical induction proceed by assuming the given $x_{n+1} \leq x_n$ rather than $x_n \leq x_{n-1}$?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  If you'd like, you can change all the $n$'s to $n+1$ and all the $n-1$'s to $n$'s.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm sorry but I can't see how this induction would be completed?

Comment: The last line is exactly $x_{n+1}\leq x_n$.

Answer (score 1):

$ x_n \geq x_{n+1} $ if and only if $x_n \geq \sqrt{2x_n+1}$ and this is true if and only if ${x_n}^2 \geq 2x_n+1$ which is same as ${x_n}^2 -2x_n-1 \geq 0$, and this expression can be written as $(x_n+\sqrt{2}-1)(x_n-\sqrt{2}-1) \geq 0$

The signs in first expression was flipped, just fixed it (Patrick was right)

So try to show that expression is always positive for every $n$

Now how do we show $x_n \geq \sqrt{2}+1$ and $x_n \geq 1-\sqrt{2}$ for every $n$  by induction?

I think Joe Johnson has better proof, follow that.

Comment: The roots of the equation are $\frac 12 \left(-(-2) \pm \sqrt{(-2)^2 - 4(-1)(1)} \right) = \frac 12 \left( 2 \pm \sqrt 8 \right) = 1 \pm \sqrt 2$. So the factorization should be 
$$
x_n^2 - 2x_n -1 = (x_n - (1+\sqrt 2))(x_n - (1-\sqrt 2))
$$
which is not the same as your expression. But you got the idea so I upvoted anyway. (I noticed this because the roots should be $a \pm \sqrt b$ something, so the sign should change on the $\sqrt{b}$, not on the other term.)

Comment: I understand what you guys have done here, but do you have any hints on how to proceed to prove that $x_n \geq (1+\sqrt{2})$ and $x_n \geq (1-\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: @Patrick I think it is the same expression without the parenthesis, i.e. $(x_n-\sqrt{2}+1)(x_n-\sqrt{2}-1)=(x_n-(\sqrt{2}-1))(x_n-(\sqrt{2}+1))$

Comment: @Jeremy : it cant be the same, the roots are not$ \sqrt 2 \pm 1$, theyre $1\pm 2$. Recall that a polynomial with two distinct roots a and b is always of the form$ (x-a)(x-b)$ or expand it correctly, youll see i am right

Comment: Hm at first i thought you said i was wrong. But yes the parenthesis.dont matter, i was putting emphasis on the roots ; it is a good mathematician reflex, since a polynomial with as many distinct roots as its degree is a product of linear factors of the form $x-a_i$, where $a_i$'s are the roots. Therefore since my roots are $1\pm \sqrt 2$ i dont want to remove my parenthesis to show the roots better.

Comment: But my expression is different from kirthi's thats for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate $x_2$, and notice that $x_{n+1}-x_n$ has the same sign as $x_{n}-x_{n-1}$, and inductively, the same sign as $x_2-x_1$, which you just calculated.