# 'Continued roots''

Tags: calculus, nested-radicals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\cdots}}}$, or the limit of the sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+x_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq)

Some time ago I was playing with a calculator and I found the following relation
$$2 = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \cdots}}}}$$
In fact I found more, I found that
$$r = \sqrt{r(r - 1) + \sqrt{r(r - 1) + \sqrt{r(r - 1) + \sqrt{r(r - 1) + \cdots}}}}$$
if $r > 1$, but I couldn't give a formal proof and I still can't.

**Note**: If you solve $r(r - 1) = 1$ then you'll find an interesting property of the golden number.

Comment: The first series converges to 2, but that doesn't mean it is equal to 2.

Comment: @Ram What do you mean by that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/115501/856

Comment: @Eu Yu, I am saying value is different from limit. The correct sentence is, 
$ \sqrt{2 + \sqrt {2 + \sqrt {2 ....}}}$ converges to $ 2$, you can't say that $ \sqrt{2 + \sqrt {2 + \sqrt {2 ....}}}$ is equal to $2$ which is wrong, since $ 2\neq  \sqrt{2 + \sqrt {2 + \sqrt {2 ....}}}$

Comment: I think the form of this question adds something to the duplicate - it illuminates the structure and gives the direct equation for the limit $L(L-1)=r(r-1)$.

Comment: @Ram, you are giving bad advice in my opinion. If you really want to be correct about it, you have to say that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to 2, where $x_n=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\ldots+\sqrt 2}}}$ ($n$ times). Your version is just as inaccurate as the OP's version (not that it matters $-$ the OP's version is perfectly acceptable in a maths forum).

Comment: @Ram It is meaningless to talk about the value of the nested radical unless there is convergence. In the case that the sequence of nested radicals $$\left\{\sqrt{2},\ \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}},\ \cdots\right\}$$ converges then we _define_ the value of the nested radical to be equal to the limit of the sequence. This is the same approach taken with infinite series. If the _limit_ is in fact equal to $2$, then there is absolutely nothing wrong with the equality.

Comment: @Eu Yu, yes agreed, but the post doesn't say anything about convergence or limit.

Comment: @Ram: And your comment doesn't say anything about what you mean by $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\ldots}}}$. Which is a much worse crime, given that you are taking it upon yourself to correct the OP. If you _had_ taken the trouble to define it, you would have seen that your final assertion is simply false: $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\ldots}}}$ is, in fact, equal to 2.

Comment: @TonyK, thanks for your comment, and regarding my last assertion, give me some time to correct myself, I mean I can't give a formal proof for that, so I will learn that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_1=\sqrt{r(r-1)}$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{r(r-1)+x_n}$ for $n \geq 1$

Then you can use $0<x_n<r$ to show that the $x_n$ are bounded above and increasing(*), which means they tend to a limit. Let that limit be x, then we have:$$x=\sqrt{r(r-1)+x}$$ which can be squared to give the solution $x=r$ (and the inadmissible $x=1-r$).

For (*) we have $$x_{n+1}-x_n=\sqrt{r(r-1)+x_n}-x_n$$ and we want to show that this is positive, so we multiply the rhs by the positive number $\sqrt{r(r-1)+x_n}+x_n$ to obtain:$$r(r-1)+x_n-x_n^2=r(r-1)-x_n(x_n-1)$$ and it remains to show that this is positive for the values required.

Answer (score 6):

As @Ram commented, if you set $a_{n+1}= \sqrt{2 + a_n}$, provided you show $a_n$ converges so there is an $L$ such that $a_n\to L$ when $n\to\infty$ and so you can solve the following equation to find $L$: $$L=\sqrt{2+L}$$. The general link is [$\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\cdots}}}$, or the limit of the sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+x_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115501/8581)

Comment: Nice link! Helpful answer! +1