# Show $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n},a_1=\sqrt2$ is monotone increasing and bounded by $2$; what is the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Let  the sequence $\{a_n\}$ be defined as $a_1 = \sqrt 2$ and $a_{n+1} = \sqrt {2+a_n}$.
>
> Show that $a_n \le$ 2 for all $n$, $a_n$ is monotone increasing, and find the limit of $a_n$.

I've been working on this problem all night and every approach I've tried has ended in failure. I keep trying to start by saying that $a_n>2$ and showing a contradiction but have yet to conclude my proof.

Comment: i've been working on this problem all night and every approach i've tried has ended in failure. i keep trying to start by saying that $a_n>2$ and showing a contradiction but have yet to conclude my proof

Comment: In the future, please [edit] your question to include information like that, instead of putting it in a comment. Many people don't bother to read the comments -- they'd miss this important bit of information.

Comment: Special case of [$\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\cdots}}}$, or the limit of the sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+x_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq)

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:**

1) Given $a_n$ is monotone increasing and bounded above, what can we say about the convergence of the sequence?

2) Assume the limit is $L$, then it must follow that $L = \sqrt{2 + L}$ (why?).  Now you can solve for a positive root.

Comment: i found the limit no problem, the part i cant do is showing that it is monotone increasing and bounded above. the point of the question is to show convergence

Comment: For the bound, Mathematical Induction seems easy.  Check $a_n \le 2 \implies 2+a_n \le 4 \implies \sqrt{2+a_n} \le ...$ you see where this goes?

Comment: "i found the limit no problem," ... why not say that in your statement.  Then Macavity would not be giving you hints on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Complementary to Macavity's answer, the following hints:

1. For boundedness: $\sqrt x$ is monotone increasing: If $x_1 < x_2$, then $\sqrt{x_1} < \sqrt{x_2}$.
2. For monotonicity: Since $a_n \le 2$ for all $n$, we have:

   $$2+a_n \ge a_n+a_n = 2a_n \ge a_n\cdot a_n = a_n^2$$