# Limit of $\{a_n\}$, where $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+a_n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, nested-radicals

I am struggling with this question:

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be defined recursively by $a_1=\sqrt2$, $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}$. Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$. HINT: Let $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$. Note that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$, so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{2+a_n}=L$. Using the properties of limits, solve for $L$.

I just don't know how I am suppose to find the limit of that or what my first step is. Any help?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Square_roots

Comment: Note that $a_{n}$ is increasing and bounded by $2$ so it tends to a limit and on solving $\sqrt{2 + L} = L$ we get $L = 2$.

Comment: Hint for a different approach: Prove by induction that $a_n=2\cos(\pi/2^{n+1})$ and use the continuity of cosine.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: I added a detailed proof of your statement as another answer.

Comment: You can find several closely related posts on this site, for example: [Show $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n},a_1=\sqrt2$ is monotone increasing and bounded by $2$; what is the limit?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553160/show-a-n1-sqrt2a-n-a-1-sqrt2-is-monotone-increasing-and-bounded-by-2),
[$\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\cdots}}}$, or the limit of the sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+x_n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501) and
[Proof Using the Monotone Convergence Theorem for the sequence $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{4 + a_n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692906)

Comment: possible duplicate of [$\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\cdots}}}$, or the limit of the sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+x_n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a recursion
of the form
$a_{n+1}
=f(a_n)
$,
if $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n
 $,
then
we must have
$L = f(L)$.

In your case,
$f(x) = \sqrt{2+x}$.

Therefore,
for any limit $L$,
we must have
$L = \sqrt{2+L}$.

Squaring,
$L^2 = L+2$,
which is a standard quadratic equation.

Completing the square,
from
$L^2-L = 2$
we get
$L^2-L+1/4
= 2+1/4
=9/4$,
so
$(L-1/2)^2 = 9/4$.

By a miracle of homework problems,
the right side is a square,
so
$(L-1/2)^2 = 9/4 = (3/2)^2$.

Taking square roots,
and remembering that
square roots can be negative
as well as positive,
we get
$L-1/2 = \pm 3/2$.
Therefore
$L = 1/2+3/2 = 2$
or
$L = 1/2 - 3/2 = -1$.

Since $L$ must be positive,
we reject the negative solution,
which goes into the corner and pouts.

This leaves only
$L=2$,
and we see by substitution
that this *does* satisfy
$L = \sqrt{2+L}$.

And they all lived happily ever after,
at least until the next problem.

Comment: Thank you! So this is a different problem I had: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=34f18a0

I am getting really strange looking 1st 4 numbers. Is that it?

Comment: $a_1 = \sqrt{2}$, $a_2 = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$, $a_3 = \sqrt{2+ \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$, $a_4 = \sqrt{2+ \sqrt{2+ \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}$.

Comment: Thank you! So I wasn't wrong after all. It just looked really unusual to me.

Comment: Nested square roots have some interesting and surprising properties. Do a search. Here is one result: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical

Comment: Are you sure that your first sentence holds without the assumption that $f$ is continuous at $L$? Anyway, you (as well as the other answerers and the hint) seem to ignore the question whether the limit exists :-)

Comment: Not so. I said that *if* the limit exists, then it must satisfy $L = f(L)$. Once $L$ has been found, the next step is to prove that it is the limit. Of course, for some problems, $L$ can not be explicitly found. The usual method then is to prove that the sequence is monotonic and bounded. That can be done in this case.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\sqrt{2+L}$$, squaring both side we have,

$$L^2-L-2=0$$

$$(L-2)(L+1)=0$$

which gives $L=2,-1$

since $a_n\gt 0$, for all $n\in \Bbb N$, Hence $L=2$

Answer (score 0):

This expands a comment of mine
to prove that the
sequence is monotonic
and bounded
and, therefore,
converges.

Suppose $a < 2$.
Then I want to show that
$a < \sqrt{2+a}
< 2$.

Let
$2-a = d > 0$.
Then $a = 2-d$.
$\sqrt{2+a}
= \sqrt{2+2-d}
= \sqrt{4-d}
< 2
$.
Also,
since
$(1-z)^2
= 1-2z + z^2
> 1-2z
$,
$\sqrt{1-2z}
> 1-z
$.
Therefore
$\sqrt{2+a}
=\sqrt{4-d}
= 2\sqrt{1-d/4}
> 2(1-d/2)
=2-d
=a
$.

Since $a_1 = \sqrt{2} < 2$,
all following
$a_n$
satisfy
$a_n < 2$
and
$a_n < a_{n+1}
$.