# Baby Rudin ("Principles of Mathematical Analysis"), chapter 3 exercise 3

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

If $s_1=\sqrt 2$,
and $$s_{n+1}=\sqrt {2+\sqrt{s_n}}$$

Prove that ${s_n}$ is converging, and that $s_n<2$ for all $n=1,2\ldots$

My attempt to use mathematical induction: if $s_n<2$ then I use
$s_{n+1}=\sqrt {2+\sqrt s_n}$, to prove $s_{n+1}<\sqrt {2+2}=2$.
I guess $s_n$ is an increasing sequence, I can use the $s_n$ is bounded and increasing, and then prove that $s_n$ converges.

Comment: Jackson.All is in place.Just work it out clearly.+

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer my question ,I figure it out

Comment: also covered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702895/find-limit-of-recursive-sequence-a-n1-sqrt2-sqrta-n?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @rtybase how you search for that I have searched before I asked but I still don’t find the answer....

Comment: I have dealt with this problem before ... just from the top of my head.

Comment: @rtybase hahaha I see

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To give a name to your idea, you want to use the monotone convergence theorem; a **bounded** and **increasing** sequence converges to the supremum of that set, indeed a standard approach would be to use induction.

> Lemma: $s_n$ is bounded

Base case:
$n=1$

$$s_1= \sqrt{2} <2$$

Suppose now for arbitrary $k$

$$ s_k< 2$$

Now observe as the inductive step:
$$ s_{k+1}=\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_k}}< \sqrt{2+2}=2$$

By the principle of mathematical induction we have found that $2$ is a bound for all $n\in
 \mathbb N$.

> Lemma: $s_n$ is increasing

Base case:
$$s_2-s_1>0$$
$$\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{\sqrt{2}}}- \sqrt{2}>\sqrt{2 + 0}- \sqrt{2}=0 $$

Now suppose for arbitrary $k$ we have:
$$ s_{k}-s_{k-1}>0 \implies s_k > s_{k-1}\implies  \sqrt{s_k}> \sqrt{s_{k-1}}$$

We now make our inductive step:
$$ s_{k+1}-s_k=\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_k}}-\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_{k-1}}}>\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_{k-1}}}-\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_{k-1}}}=0$$
Hence we have an increasing sequence for all $n \in \mathbb N$ this completes the proof and our sequence is indeed convergent $\square$.

Answer (score 7):

Your idea is perfect.  The [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) guarantees convergence of a sequence if you can show that the sequence is increasing and bounded above (or decreasing and bounded below). To get that your sequence is increasing, the trick is to use [*strong* induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction):

The base case is easy, so I'll leave that to you.  Next, suppose that each subsequent term is larger than the previous for each of the first $k$ terms.  We want to show $s_{k+1} > s_k$, and because we used strong induction, we can assume $s_{k} > s_{k-1}$, which gives the inequality $s_{k+1} = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_k}} > \sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_{k-1}}}$.  And what is $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_{k-1}}} \ $?

This argument is implicitly using the fact that $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is an increasing function, but this is fairly easy to prove.

---

If you wanted to actually find the limit of the sequence, first note that $\{s_{n+1} \}$ is a subsequence of $\{s_n\}$.  If $ \{s_n \}$ converges, any subsequence also converges to the same value.  Taking a limit of both sides of that equality, we get:

$$\lim(s_{n+1}) = \lim \left( \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_n}} \right)$$

Applying limit laws, and recognizing that $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is a continuous function$^\dagger$, we'll have:

$$\lim(s_{n+1}) = \sqrt{ 2 + \sqrt{ \lim(s_n)}}$$

We know $\{s_n\}$ converges to some $L \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $\{s_{n+1} \}$ to the same, so the above reduces to:

$$L = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{L}}$$

Solving for $L$, we find that it is a root of the quartic $L^4 - 4L^2 - L + 4$.  Notice that $1$ is a root, so we can factor out $(L-1)$, reducing the problem to finding roots of the cubic $L^3 + L^2 - 3L - 4$.  You can find its three roots using the [cubic formula](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/) (two of them will have nonzero imaginary part, so our $L$ will be the single real root).  The cubic formula is a mess, so you can also arrive at an arbitrarily good approximation for $L$ using [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).  Either way, we get $L \approx 1.8312$.

---

$^\dagger$We're applying the fact that, if $f$ is a continuous function and $\{a_n\}$ a convergent sequence in the domain of $f$, then $a_n \to M \implies f(a_n) \to f(M)$.

Comment: in fact I want to know how to prove $s_n$ is increasing

Comment: I know the fact you add,but I still don’t understand why $s_n$ is increasing

Comment: Added!  And ugh, I have no idea why my TeX isn't rendering in the bit I added.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There we go, lol

Comment: Oh, just realized you weren't actually asked to find the value to which it converges.  Well, that's how you'd do it!  Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

It is a fixed point iteration of the form $s_{n+1}=g(s_n)$. You can easily check that $g([0,2]) \subset [0,2]$ an so, if you start with $s_1 \in [0,2]$, the sequence will remain in $[0,2]$, which proves part of the question. Regarding convergence, you can use again the properties of $g$ to check that the sequence in monotone, like you guessed. Note that you can look at $g$ as a real function and use differential calculus...

Comment: It's kind of cheating to use tools of differential calculus when you are still building it up and technically "it does not exist yet"

Comment: But great answer :)

Comment: Sure @WesleyStrik, it is a little bit cheating :), but it is also a bit more general in the sense that you could prove convergence (Banach's fixed point) even without monotonicity.

Answer (score 2):

Wesley's lemma 1 nicely shows that $s_n$ is bounded above.

Rephrasing:

Show that $s_n$ is increasing:

1) $n=1$: $s_2 > s_1√$

2) Hypothesis : $s_{n+1} \ge s_n.$

Step  $n+1:$

$s_{n+2} =\sqrt{2+√s_{n+1}} {Hyp. \atop \ge} \sqrt{2+√s_n} =s_{n+1}.$

Used: $f(x)=√x$ is an increasing function.

Comment: You give a nice proof!

Comment: Jackson.Thanks, once I got your lead, not so very difficult:))