# The sequence $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}},...$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, fixed-point-theorems

Prove that the sequence $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}},...$ converges and find its limit.  Prove this without using derivatives (*Source: Based on Abbot's Analysis*).

### Proof (partial)

Let $f$ be an increasing function with fixed point $k$, such that $x \leq k \implies x \leq f(x) \leq k$.  Let $a$ be a sequence $a_1 \leq k, a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$.  By induction, $a$ is bounded and increasing, and therefore converges.  Furthermore, if $x < k \implies f(x) > x$, $a$ converges to $k$.

Let $g(x) = \sqrt{x+2}, g > 0$.  $g$ is increasing, with fixed point $g(2) = 2$.  By properties of ordered fields, $x < 2 \implies g(x) < 2$.  It remains to show that $x < 2 \implies g(x) > x$.  This can be proven by taking the derivative of $x - \sqrt{x+2}$, but **I'm not able to prove it without derivatives**.

$a_1 = \sqrt{2} < 2, a_{n+1} = g(a_n)$, QED.

### Questions

1. Can you help me fill in the missing part?
2. Critique what I've done (both the proof and the writing).
3. It seems that functions with the property $f(x) > x$ would be very important for studying series.  Is there a name for them? Do they have any other salient properties?
4. Instead of simply tackling the problem locally, in terms of $\sqrt{2}$, I abstracted it to more general series.  Is that advisable? What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: If you want to show $\sqrt{x+2}>x$ for $-2<x<2$, it's equivalent to show $x+2>x^2 \text{sign}(x)$ over the same range; why is this more tractable?

Comment: You can compare your proof with the versions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585780/show-that-the-sequence-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2/).

Comment: if $-1<x<2$ then $x^2-x-2=(x+1)(x-2)<0$ so $x^2<x+2$ so $x<g(x)$

Comment: In regard to your 4th question, you have overgeneralized. Consider the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac 12x+1 &(x<2) \\ \frac 12x+2 &(x\ge 2) \end{cases}$ with $k=4$ and $a_1=0$. This meets the conditions under which you claim $a_n$ converges to $k$, but in fact $a_n$ converges to $2$.

Comment: For a completely different approach to the problem, try applying the identity $x-y = \dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x+y}$ to $x=2$, $y=a_n$. (I still think you should pursue your original idea too, but I couldn't resist posting a cute alternative!)

Comment: Why not just solving the equation and pick the positive solution $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$?

Comment: @Moti:  did you mean the equation $\sqrt{x+2}=x$, which has positive solution $2$?

Comment: @Moti, the fixed point is $2$, not $(1+\sqrt 5)/2$. But more importantly, that doesn't prove convergence. Compare the sequence $a_1=1$, $a_{n+1}=2a_n+1$. The equation $x=2x+1$ has solution $x=-1$ but this is not the limit of $a_n$.

Comment: @Tuna Assuming convergence leads to the equation $x^2 = 2 +x$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes.

Comment: @Tuna It seems you right and my assumption for the equation was not right.