# Looking for a solution to $f(x)^2 = 1 + x f(x + 1)$

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations

This difference equation
$$
f(x)^2 = 1 + x f(x + 1) 
$$
can pop up when looking at a famous problem posted by Ramanujan.

This equation is equivalent to the following infinitely nested radical expression
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{1 + x \sqrt{1 + (x+1) \sqrt{1 + (x+2)\sqrt{\cdots}}}}
$$
assuming that we take the positive branch of all of the radicals.

Ok, what I would like to prove or disprove is whether the only analytic (or a more relaxed criterion) solution is $f(x) = 1+x$. You can easily enough show that if $f$ is differentiable, then $f(N) = 1+N$ for all integers $N\in\mathbb{Z}$.

You can also show that for all integers
$$
f'(N) = a N 2^N + 1
$$
for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$ by solving the recurrence relation that appears after taking the derivative of the above difference equation. It is clear that $f(x) = 1+x$ is a solution, but I am trying to figure out if it is the only solution.

Comment: What work have you yourself undertaken.  Please clarify more specific questions as to what you don't understand, or where you are stuck.  This is not a "solve these questions for me" sort of site.  Please add sufficient context.

Comment: Check [this posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3119631/9340) and the answers therein.

Comment: It doesn't seem so easy to show $f(N)=1+N$ for integers.

Comment: @amWhy I feel like I have included a fair amount of context. Essentially while looking at various sources on stackexchange and otherwise a few times I came across the claim that says you can show that $f=1+x$ if $f$ is analytic, but I do not see how. I showed that I can prove that it is true for integers, and I also derived a necessary expression for the first derivative of the solution evaluated at integers, but that is where my leads run dry, hence why I created a post.

Comment: @aschepler

By setting $x = 0$, and $x=-1$ you find that $f(0) = 1$ and $f(-1) = 0$. 
By taking the implicit derivative and looking at $x=0$ and $x=-1$ again, you find that $f'(0) = 1$ and thus $f(1)=2$ the rest follow by induction.

Comment: I think that I might have a path forward here. You can show that if $f$ is polynomial, then it must be $f(x)=1+x$, and I wonder if something like Weierstrass approximation theorem can take us the rest of the way through a proof by contradiction.

Comment: I don't find that $f(0)=1$. $f(0) \in \{1,-1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $g : (0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be some arbitrary function.
Define $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1&x = 0\\g(x)&x\in(0,1]\\\dfrac{f^2(x-1) - 1}{x-1} & x\in(1,\infty)\end{cases}$$
Where the last is applied inductively. If desired, the recursion can also be adapted to define $f$ on $(-\infty, 0)$. Because of the recursion, the relation $f^2(x) = 1+xf(x+1)$ holds everywhere for $x$.

Thus you see, there are uncountably many functions satisfying the equation. Even if we require $f$ to be infinitely differentiable, this will still be true. We just need $g$ to be infinitely differentiable and specify a relation between its behavior approaching $0$ and approaching $1$.

It is only analycity - specifically about $x = 1$ - that is a strong enough requirement to actually tame this beast.

The nested square roots expression either converges to a specific function satisfying the recursion formula, or else it diverges. It is not fully equivalent to the recursion formula.

Comment: This is interesting. Can you come up with an infinitely differentiable example (specifically near $x=1$ seems very tricky)

Comment: I'm thinking that $g(x) = x+1+\exp{\left(-\tfrac{1}{x^2(x-1)^2}\right)}$ might be able to do it. I'm not able to play with it now, but it's hard to see why it wouldn't work as a counter example.

Comment: You already know one infinitely differentiable example: $g(x) = 1 + x$ leads to $f(x) = 1 + x$. More generally, my claims about smooth functions are indeed based on the bump function. As long as $g$ behaves like $1+x$ at both ends, you can bump it to do whatever you want in the middle.