# Are my results new?

Tags: interpolation, pi

I'm eighteen and sometimes I like doing math on my own when I'm inspired. I would like to know if some of my "discoveries" are new (I don't think so :) ). These are some of the results I found in the last 3 years:

**Infinite radical converging to pi**
$$\pi= \lim_{x\to\infty} 2^x\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}}} \tag{1}$$
Where in the radical there are $x$ numbers $2$

**Determinant of a matrix for the interpolation of polynomials**

Let $p(x)=[a_n,a_{n-1},...,a_1,a_0]$ be a polynomial passing through $n+1$ points $P_i(x_i,y_i)$ . This polynomial is intrinsically connected with the matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & ... & x_1^{n-1} & x_1^{n} \\ 
1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & ... & x_2^{n-1} & x_2^{n} \\ 
. &  & . &  & . & \\ 
. &  &  & . & . & \\ 
1 & x_{n-1} & x_{n-1}^2 & ... & x_{n-1}^{n-1} & x_{n-1}^{n} \\ 
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & ... & x_n^{n-1} & x_n^{n} \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \tag{2}$$

Moreover:
$$det\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & ... & x_1^{n-1} & x_1^{n} \\ 
1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & ... & x_2^{n-1} & x_2^{n} \\ 
. &  & . &  & . & \\ 
. &  &  & . & . & \\ 
1 & x_{n-1} & x_{n-1}^2 & ... & x_{n-1}^{n-1} & x_{n-1}^{n} \\ 
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & ... & x_n^{n-1} & x_n^{n} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}=\prod _{k>j} (x_k-x_j) \tag{3}$$

**Bounds for the sum of prime factors**

Let $\ \Pi(x)\ $ be the function that gives in output the [sum of the primes factors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofPrimeFactors.html) of $x$ for example $\ \Pi(8)=6,\ $ then:
$$\log_3(x^3)\leq \Pi(x) \leq x \tag{4}$$

**An alternative formula for the divisor function**

$\sigma_0(x)$ is defined as the function that gives in output the number of divisors of $x$, then:
$$\sigma_0(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x  \log_x\left ( i^{\left \lfloor \frac{x}{i} \right \rfloor-\left \lfloor \frac{x-1}{i} \right \rfloor}\frac{\left \lfloor \frac{x}{i} \right \rfloor!}{\left \lfloor \frac{x-1}{i} \right \rfloor!} \right ) \tag{5}$$

**Conjecture about the n-nacci period**

Let $\ T(n)\ $ be the function the gives in output the $n$-nacci period, i.e. the periodicity of the units digit in a $n$-nacci sequence with all of the starting terms that are equal to $1$ ($T(2)=60$ is the classic Fibonacci sequence). Then my conjecture is that:

$$T(2n+1)=\frac{5^{2n+1}-1}{4} \tag{6}$$

Clearly, $n$ is integer. I almost forgot $2n+1$ must not terminate with digit $1$ (in that case the problem is trivial).

I hope you can tell me whether this results are trivial or not and if they are eventually wrong. Thank you for the time :) .

Comment: That's the Vandermonde determinant.

Comment: This is definitely impressive work! Good job! :) Your matrix is called "Vandermonde" matrix, which is known to have an inverse if $x_i\neq x_j$ for all $i\neq j$. It is definitely impressive that you have discovered that by yourself.

Comment: I'm sure it converges https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E7+sqrt(2-sqrt(2%2Bsqrt(2%2Bsqrt(2%2Bsqrt(2%2Bsqrt(2%2Bsqrt(2))))))). Thank you :) .

Comment: You are right; I have thought that you put alternating $\pm$s there.

Comment: The approximation of pi can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula), it is usually derived from Viète's formula. And a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) for the Vandermonde Matrix.

Comment: @Javi thank you  i didn't know about that formula.

Comment: For inequalities with sums of prime factors: http://m-hikari.com/imf/imf-2012/53-56-2012/jakimczukIMF53-56-2012-2.pdf

Comment: Keep up the good work. You can't be expected to find something truly new without extensive background, but it happens. Quite recently random people on the internet with no math background have made advances, and one of them was added as an author to a paper on the results, as anonymous.

Comment: @st.math 2012? Just 7 years ago: that was near! :)

Comment: The first formula works but only if you make sure the number of square roots matches the power of two indicated by x.

Comment: @poetasis I specified under that the number of two(that equals the number of roots) must be equal to x.

Comment: Archimedes discovered the first (more or less); so you're in good company.

Comment: @DavidMitra indeed i used the exhaustion method of Archimedes.

Comment: @Eureka: As others have mentioned, at least a few of your discoveries are not new. That doesn't diminish your accomplishments, however. As the late Steve Fisk once advised: *It's only an accident of time that someone else got there before you.*

Comment: @Blue Thank you , I started a bounty because I'm curious to know about the other ones :)

Comment: I envy you, you have a big world to discover and you'll probably explore a good deal of it. The bounds for the sum of prime factors is mentioned here http://oeis.org/A001414

Comment: A little bit searching on the site gives [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/649968/11619). The outermost square root with a minus sign converts it to a sine. After that you have an instance of the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1.$$ But, good job coming up with this.

Comment: I'm afraid I still vote to close this question. You should only have one question per post. Otherwise it is impossible to point at duplicates of each part. It is not intended to be personal, so please don't take it as such. Just a clinical application of site rules.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm really sorry. It was my first post and it wasn't my intention to cause problems :( . Should I cancel it?

Answer (score 5):

**About the determinant:**

Such a matrix is said to be of the Vandermonde form.

Its determinant is obviously a polynomial in the $x_i$. It must cancel whenever two $x_i$ are equal (making two equal rows), so that it must be a multiple of every $(x_i-x_j)$. There are $\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$ such factors. On another hand, the degree of the polynomial must be the the sum of the degrees along a row, i.e. the $n^{th}$ triangular number, $\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$. This is enough to say that

$$\det M=m\prod_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)$$ for some nonzero constant $m$.

---

**About the infinite radical:**

You must be careful about this notation because you don't say what is "at the end of the dots". You can express the nested radicals as a recurrence

$$r_{n+1}=\sqrt{r_n+2},$$ but some $r_0$ must be specified. If you take $r_0=2$, then for all $n$, $r_n=2$ and… $\pi=0$ !

You probably obtained your formula from the perimeter of the circle, by successive doublings of the number of sides, using the angle halving formula

$$2\cos\frac x2=\sqrt{2\cos x + 2}$$ and $x=\dfrac\pi{2^m}$ for some $m$. Then starting from $m=1$, $r_0=0$, and your estimates of $\pi$ are

$$2^n\sin\frac\pi{2^n}.$$

Congratulations, you rejoined Archimedes' findings !

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: what an unfriendly and inappropriate remark! I am not after "points". I am addressing the question of the OP willing to know if his findings are correct/known.

Comment: And failed to search for dupes, and did not notice that the question has three questions compressed to one in violation of the site rules. It is fine to be friendly to newbies, but they also need guidance about the site norms.

Comment: I concede that there is room for differences of opinion here, but from the point of view of site curation it does not really make a difference whether your *just post and not worry about duplicates* -approach is due to hunger for points or for something else.