# Trig and de Moivre's theorem

Tags: trigonometry

> A) Use de Moivre's theorem to prove that $\cos^4\theta = 8\cos^4\theta - 8\cos^2\theta + 1$
>
> B) Therefore deduce that $\cos(\pi/8) = \left(\frac{2 + \sqrt{2}}{4}\right)^{1/2}$
>
> C) and write down an expression for $\cos(3\pi/8)$.

I have proved the first part of the question but I am not sure where to go from there.

My attempt

de Moivre's theorem states that $(\cos x +i\sin x)^n = \cos nx + i\sin nx$

using this and $\cos ^2θ + \sin ^2θ =1$, I did the following:

\begin{align}
\cos 4θ + i\sin 4θ &= (\cos θ +i\sin θ)^4 + \cos 4θ + 4i\cos ^3θ\sin θ - 6\cos ^2θ\sin ^2θ-4i\cos θ\sin 3θ+\sin ^4θ\\
\cos 4θ &= \cos ^4θ -6\cos ^2θ\sin ^2θ +\sin ^4θ\\
\cos 4θ &= \cos ^4θ - 6\cos ^2θ(1-\cos ^2θ) + (1-\cos ^2θ)^2\\
\cos 4θ &= \cos ^4θ - 6\cos ^2θ + 6\cos ^4θ +1 - 2\cos ^2θ + \cos ^θ\\
\cos 4θ &= 8\cos ^4θ -8\cos ^2θ +1
\end{align}

Comment: I’m Japanese. So if you want to talk in Japanese, please tell me mailadress.

Comment: Are you sure you have posted the right equation?

Comment: C-RAM meant that you should edit your question to include your attempt.  People might miss your attempt if you leave it in the comments.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Welcome to MathSE.

Comment: Thank you for your tips everyone, I have listened and edited the post to contain my proof/attempt for the first part of the question.

Comment: @user170231 

Yes you are correct, it should be changed now. Many thanks for the correction

Comment: Hint: let $c:=\cos\frac{\pi}{8}$ so $8(c^2)^2-8c^2+1=\cos\frac{\pi}{2}=0$. Solve this quadratic in $c^2$, then argue $c^2>\cos^2\frac{\pi}{4}$ to decide which root is applicable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted, the firt proposition should be

$\cos 4\theta = 8\cos^4\theta - 8\cos^2\theta + 1$

What you show is fine.

What is $\cos \frac {\pi}{8}$?

$\cos 4\frac {\pi}{8} = 8\cos^4\frac {\pi}{8} - 8\cos^2\frac {\pi}{8} +1\\
\cos \frac {\pi}{2} = 0 =8\cos^4\frac {\pi}{8} - 8\cos^2\frac {\pi}{8} +1$

Let $u = \cos \frac{\pi}{8}$

$8u^4 - 8u^2 + 1 = 0$

Apply the quadratic formula.
$u^2 = \frac {8\pm\sqrt{64-32}}{16} = \frac 12 \pm \frac {\sqrt{2}}{4}$

$u = \pm \sqrt {\frac 12 \pm \frac {\sqrt{2}}{4}}$

But this gives 4 answers... how do we make sense of that?

All values of $\cos(\frac {(2n+1)\pi}{8})$ will solve $8u^4-8u^2 + 1$

$\cos \frac {\pi}{8} = \sqrt {\frac 12 + \frac {\sqrt{2}}{4}}\\
\cos \frac {3\pi}{8} = \sqrt {\frac 12 - \frac {\sqrt{2}}{4}}\\
\cos \frac {5\pi}{8} = -\sqrt {\frac 12 - \frac {\sqrt{2}}{4}}\\
\cos \frac {7\pi}{8} = -\sqrt {\frac 12 + \frac {\sqrt{2}}{4}}$

Answer (score 5):

With $\cos(4\theta)$ on the lhs, you can substitute $\theta = \frac{\pi}{8}$ in your first equation, which gives a polynomial equation for $\cos(\frac{\pi}{8})$.

$$0 = 8\cos^4\frac{\pi}{8}- 8\cos^2\frac{\pi}{8} + 1$$

This equation is biquadratic and can be solved with the quadratic formula to show that,

$$\cos\frac{\pi}{8} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$$

You can use related [methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/649968/738509) to show that,

\begin{align}
\cos\frac{\pi}{4}  &= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2} \\
\cos\frac{\pi}{8}  &= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} \\
\cos\frac{\pi}{16} &= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}} \\
\cos\frac{\pi}{32} &= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}} \\
\cos\frac{\pi}{64} &= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}
\end{align}

and the pattern goes on

Comment: Do not understand why this post and my answer got so many upvotes :0