# Prove that sequence $a_1 = \sqrt{2}$, $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 + a_n}$ is bounded above by 3

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, induction

I need a little bit of help (just a hint, please) with an induction proof on this sequence, which I need to prove is bounded above by 3.
$$
a_1 = \sqrt{2}
$$
$$
a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 + a_n}
$$

My attempt:
$$
a_k < 3
$$
$$
a_k + 2 < 5
$$
$$
\sqrt{a_k + 2} < \sqrt{5}
$$
$$
a_{k+1} < \sqrt{5}
$$
... and I don't know where to go from here.

If I were to find a limit of this sequence, which way would I have to go? Should I try to rewrite the sequence into a formula?

Comment: You are done. Just use $\sqrt{5} < \sqrt{9} =3$.

Comment: It is even bounded above by $2$.  In fact, $a_n$ increases to $2$ as $n$ goes up.

Comment: I wonder how many students have been led down blind alleys by devious teachers who play on the difference between upper bound and least upper bound.

Comment: @BrianTung The least upper bound of an increasing sequence is its limit, right?

Comment: Yes, if it exists.

Comment: There is [an older version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449592/evaluating-the-limit-of-a-sequence-given-by-recurrence-relation-a-1-sqrt2-a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have $a_{k+1} < \sqrt{5}$, you can use that $\sqrt{5} < 3$ to prove that $a_{k+1} < 3$. Hence by induction all terms of this sequence are bounded by $3$.

Now for the limit part, your sequence is bounded above, if you can show that it is an increasing sequence then it follows (see a theorem about monotone convergence) that the sequence should have a limit. Once that is established you can assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=a$. Now you have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n}}.$$
Solve for $a$.

Comment: And how to you solve for $a$ here? @Anurag A

Comment: Because if you let $L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_{n+1} = \lim_{n 
 \rightarrow \infty}a_n$ you get the equation $L = \sqrt{2 + L}$ and then $L^2 = L + 2 = L^2 - L - 2 = 0$ and then $(L - 2)(L + 1) = 0$, so you get $L_1 = 2$ and $L_2 = -1$. But what to do with $L_2 = -1$?

Comment: @user124942 Since the sequence consists of all positive terms so the limit cannot be negative. Thus your limit is $L_1=2$.

Comment: Ok. Cool. ;) Problem solved. ;) @Anurag A

Answer (score 0):

How to find a limit of recursive sequence $$a_{n+1} = \dfrac{a_n^2 + 1}{2}$$? @Anurag A

Comment: 1.dont post questions as answer

2.suppose there is a limit and solve for it

Comment: Is there $$L = \frac{L^2 + 1}{2}$$ and then solve for $L$? @Arjang

Comment: explain to yourself why, you already know, just need to justify it to yourself

Answer (score 0):

Then you can write $$a_{k+1}<\sqrt 5<3$$therefore $a_k<3$ means $a_{k+1}<3$. Since $a_1=\sqrt 2<3$ therefore $a_2<3,a_3<3,a_4<3,\cdots $ and $a_k<3$ for all $k$.