# Examine the following sequences of numbers $(a_n)$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for the properties of monotonicity and boundedness.

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

As per the title, I need to examine the following sqeuences of numbers $(a_n)$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for the properties of monotonicity and boundedness. These sequences are given via the following functions, which are to be examined:

1. $a_n = \frac{n^2}{n!}$
2. $b_n = \frac{(-2)^{n+1}+3^n}{3^{n+1}+(-2)^n}$
3. $c_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+c_n}; c_0 = \sqrt{2}$

---

Since sequences are a new topic for me, I will refer to the following definitions:

- Sequence (mathematics): (here) The resulting ordered set of numbers produced from a function.
- [Monotonicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Increasing_and_decreasing)
- [Boundedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Bounded)

Also, here I am avoiding limits as I believe they are being purposely excluded from this task.

---

---

Progress so far:

1. Here I wasn't really sure what to expect, so i just decided to substitute $n = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ which produces the set $\{0, 1, 2, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{2}{3}\}$. So from observation, the set of numbers is increasing until the value of $b_2$, but then the set is decreasing. Thus, before any proof, it would appear that the function $a$ is monotonically decreasing, but not strictly.

To prove this, I write an inequality with $n$ and $n + 1$.

$
\begin{align*}
\frac{n^2}{n!} &> \frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)!} \\
\frac{n^2}{n!} &> \frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)n!} \\
n^2 &> \frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)} \\
n^2 &> n + 1 \\
\end{align*}
$

By substituting values for n it can be seen that the function is monotonically decreasing from n $\geq 2$.

To prove boundedness, for the upper bound we observe that $\frac{n^2}{n!} \leq 2$ (supremum). For the lower bound we consider that $n!$ grows faster than $n^2$, and both are always greater than $0$. Thus $n^2/n!$ will tend towards the (lower bound) value of $0$ (infimum).

Thus, **$a_n$ is nonstrictly monotonically decreasing and bounded**.

---

2. Here, the first thing I notice is that the sign of the function changes every time n increases. So according to the definition I would reason that the function is neither increasing nor decreasing, i.e the function is not monotonic.

the second thing that I notice is that the function is composed of powers of (negative) 2 and 3. Since powers of 3 grow faster than powers of 2, I reason that for very large values of n the function will tend towards $\frac{3^n}{3^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{3}$ (the infimum and supremum are the same), i.e **$b_n$ is non-monotonic but bounded** (This feels very non-rigorous however, is there a better way of handling this question?)

---

3. This function appears to have been given in recursive notation (as opposed to index notation). The first 3 values are as follows:

\begin{align*}
c_0 &= \sqrt{2} \\
c_1 &= \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}} \\
c_2 &= \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}\\
\end{align*}

Monotonicity: Since more terms are added for each successive recursive call, and the elements are greater than zero, I would reason that the function is monotonically increasing.

For the boundedness of the function, After plugging a few values into wolfram, it appears that this sequence tends towards 2.

Can anyone offer some pointers? At this stage I get stuck.

Comment: An advice for your proofs of monotony and boundedness (Question 1 and 2).   You could use what you did to write a **proof by induction** (as I did in my answer for question 3). Finally, The argument of *domination* to find the limit of division of sequences is totally valid.

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449592/evaluating-the-limit-of-a-sequence-given-by-recurrence-relation-a-1-sqrt2-a

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the 3rd question since I think you did pretty good for the first two.

$$c_{n+1}=f(c_n)$$

with $f(x)=\sqrt{2+x}$ and $c_0=\sqrt 2$

1. Prove by recurrence that $\forall n \geq 0, \ \sqrt2 \leq \ c_n\leq 2 $:

   . $\sqrt2 \leq \ c_0\leq 2 $ is true

   . $$\begin{align}  
     \sqrt2 & \leq \ c_n  & \leq & 2  \\
     2+\sqrt2 &  \leq \ 2+c_n & \leq  & 2+2  \\
     \sqrt{2+\sqrt2} & \leq  \ \sqrt{2+c_n} & \leq  & \sqrt{2+2}    \\
     \sqrt{2} & \leq \ c_{n+1} & \leq & 2 
   \end{align}$$
2. Prove that $\forall x\in [\sqrt 2 , 2] , \ |f'(x)|\leq \lambda < 1$
   $$f'(x)=|f'(x)| = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2+x}} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}} = \lambda <1 $$
3. Prove existence and uniqueness of the fixed point of $f$ i.e: $\exists! \alpha \in [\sqrt 2, 2]$ s.t  $f(\alpha) = \alpha $
   $$\begin{align}  x \in [\sqrt 2, 2],\  f(x) =x & \iff \sqrt{2+x}=x \\ & \iff x^2-x-2 =0  & (\mathrm{because \ }x>0) \\ & \iff x=2  & (\mathrm{because \ }x>0)   \end{align}$$
4. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = 2$
   $$ c_{n+1} = f(c_n) \iff  \alpha-c_{n+1} = f(\alpha)-f(c_n) $$

f is continuous we can apply the mean value theorem $\exists a_n \in (c_n, \alpha)$ s.t $ f(\alpha) - f(c_n) = f'(a_n)(\alpha - c_n) \iff \alpha - c_{n+1} = f'(a_n)(\alpha - c_n)  $

Yet, $ \forall n\geq 0, \ f'(a_n)\leq \lambda <1$ so $$0< \alpha - c_{n+1} \leq \lambda ^n (\alpha-c_0) \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} c_n  = \alpha = 2$$

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded yet. for parts a and b, thanks for the verification and the kind words. For part c, I had some trouble understanding why each step was taken. I need to consult the answer linked in the comments before I can make any progress with this question.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st one, you can see that $\frac{n^2}{n!}=\frac{n}{(n-1)!}=\frac{n+1-1}{(n-1)!}=\frac{1}{(n-2)!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\leq1+1=2, \forall n\geq2$ where $a_1=1$ so $a_n\leq2$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Also, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{n^2}{n!}}=\frac{(n+1)^2n!}{n^2(n+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2(n+1)}=\frac{n+1}{n^2}\leq1,\forall n\geq2$ , so $a_n$ is decreasing sequence for all $n\in\Bbb N$ since $a_1=2>\frac{3}{4}=a_2$.