# Let $a_1=\sqrt{6},a_{n+1}=\sqrt{6+a_n}$. Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n-3)6^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $a_1=\sqrt{6}$, $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{6+a_n}$. Find $\lim\limits_{n \to
>  \infty} (a_n-3)6^n$.

First, we may obtain $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=3$. Hence, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(a_n-3)b^n$ belongs to a type of limit with the form $0 \cdot \infty$.

Moreover, we obtained a similar result [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h588201p3482175), which is related to the form $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n-3)9^n$.

How should I proceed?

Comment: I think it can be solved using [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) but I really don't know how to proceed.

Comment: The result depends on the initial condition, Stolz-Cesaro does not look promising here.

Comment: There is a typo in the bounty text, it should be $L = \lim_{n \to \infty}(3-a_n)6^n$.

Comment: @MartinR why don't you edit it? ...

Comment: @lonestudent: Bounty descriptions cannot be edited. Perhaps moderators can do it (I have asked them) but mere mortals can't.

Comment: @MartinR thank you for clarification .I understood.:) I'm looking forward to the answers. It would be incredible if the answer contains constants other than $\pi$. But the important thing is to have a striking answer :)

Comment: More generally, it might be interesting to consider $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{c(c-1)+a_n}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\left(a_n-c\right)(2c)^n\right)$. But the general case is probably even more difficult than this specific case with $c = 3$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla: the convergence of that limit follows also along the method outlined by GabrielRomon. Generally speaking, $-\log(1/2c)=\lambda=\lim_n\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\log(f'(a_k))$,  is the Lyapunov exponent of the system $a_n=f(a_{n-1})$ with $f(x)=\sqrt{c(c-1)+x}$. The system has a strong tractor $c$ and the limit in question is $\lim_n (a_n-c)e^{-n \lambda}$. This is why the problem is difficult.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Right, I specifically chose that base on the exponent so that it doesn't converge to $0$ for all $a_0$ and doesn't diverge (or at least I think I chose it correctly). It's just a generalization that I thought would be interesting.

Comment: Re the bounty part, @MartinR, this book [Asymptotic Methods in Analysis, N. G. de Bruijn](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Asymptotic-Methods-Analysis-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486642216), page 151, describes an analytic method of solving the problem, for $b_n$ given
$$b_{n+1}=\sqrt{9+b_n}-3$$
$$f(x)=\sqrt{9+x}-3, f(0)=0$$
[and](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%289%2Bx%29%20-%203)
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{6}-\frac{x^2}{216}+\frac{x^3}{3888}-\frac{5 x^4}{279936}+...$$
with $$0<a_1=\frac{1}{6}<1$$

Comment: Page 151, shows that $\frac{b_n}{a_1^n}$ tends to a limit and page 152 shows
$$b_n=\Omega(a_1^n\cdot\omega(b_0))$$
where $$\omega(f(x))=a_1\omega(x)$$
([Schröder's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%27s_equation)) and $\Omega$ is [Lagrange inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) of $\omega$, i.e. $\Omega(\omega(x))=x$.

Comment: @rtybase: Thanks for the reference. Is that related to what H. H. Rugh writes in their answer?

Comment: Almost, but I think Somos is closer, with the reference to the [Koenigs function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koenigs_function) (and Schröder's equation).

Comment: If you let the limit be a function of $a_0$ as $f(a_0)$, then $f'(a_0) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3^n}{a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_n}$, where $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$ are all functions of $a_0$ and $f(3) = 0$.

Comment: Fascinating. I will think about this.

Comment: Reminds me of "pi in the mandelbrot "

Answer (score 14):

The function, $a_1 \mapsto \Phi(a_1) = \lim_{n\to \infty} 6^n (a_n-3)$  is a well-known object in complex dynamics and known as a linearization map. It solves a conjugation problem, which was first introduced by Ernst Schröder in 1871 to study iterations of rational functions. You may find an account e.g. in Carleson and Gamelin: Complex Dynamics. In chap II.2 we have the following:

Theorem 2.1: Suppose an analytic function $f$ has an attractive fixed point $p$ with multiplier $\lambda=f'(p)$ satisfying $0<|\lambda|<1$. Then there is a conformal map $\zeta=\phi(z)$ (unique up to scaling) of a neighborhood of $p$ onto a neighborhood of $0$ which conjugates $f(z)$ to the linear function $g(\zeta)=\lambda \zeta$.

The proof goes through the construction of the limit you mention. To be more explicit and using your example: Let $D={\Bbb C}\setminus (-\infty;-6]$ be the slit complex plane. Then $f(z)=\sqrt{z+6}$ defines a conformal map of $D$ into the right half plane ${\Bbb H}_+\subset D$. Thus, for all $z\in D$: $$|f(z)-3| = \left|\frac{z-3}{\sqrt{z+6}+3}\right| \leq \frac13 |z-3|$$
Thus we have convergence of $f^n(z)$ to the fixed point $p=3$, uniformly on compact subsets of $D$.
We also have $\lambda=f'(3) = \frac16$.

The proof of the theorem is then to show that the sequence of maps ($n\geq 0$):
$$ \phi_n(z) = \lambda^{-n} (f^n(z)-p) = 6^n (f^n(z)-3)$$
converges uniformly on a neighborhood of $p$.
Pick $z_0=z\in D$ and let $z_n=f^n(z_0)$ (I prefer starting at index 0 so that we iterate $f$ as many times as the linear map) we have:
$$ \phi_{n+1}(z) = 6^n (z_n-3) \frac{6}{\sqrt{z_n+6}+3} =
\phi_n(z) \left(1 + \frac{3-\sqrt{z_n+6}}{\sqrt{z_n+6}+3}\right) =
\phi_n(z) \left( 1 + \epsilon(z_n)\right)
$$
where  $$\epsilon(z_n) = \frac{3-z_n}{\left( \sqrt{6+z_n} + 3\right)^2}. $$
One has $|\epsilon(z_n)| \leq \frac19 |z_n-3| \leq \frac{1}{3^{n+2}} |z-3|$
thus going to zero exponentially fast and uniformly on compact subsets in $D$. It follows that the limit $$\phi(z) = \lim_n \phi_n(z)=(z-3)\prod_{n\geq 1} (1+\epsilon(z_n))$$ exists and is holomorphic in $D$.
The function verifies $\phi'(3)=1$ whereas your function has an extra factor $6$ since your index starts with $n=1$ rather than zero. So your function is really $\Phi(a_1)=6\phi(a_1)$. The formula is numerically precise and efficient: $6\phi(\sqrt{6})=-3.36565753974384...$ in agreement with other results posted.

To see that $\phi$ actually yields a solution to the Theorem, note that by construction we have $\lambda^{-1} \phi_n\circ f = \phi_{n+1}$. By uniform convergence we may take limits to get $\lambda^{-1} \phi\circ f = \phi$ or $\phi \circ f = \lambda \phi = g\circ \phi$, with $g(\zeta)=\lambda \zeta$ being the linear map.

A Taylor expansion of $\phi$ may be obtained from the functional equation $6\phi(\sqrt{z+6}) =  \phi(z)$ by expanding at $z_0=3$ on both sides and identifying coefficients. A far more elegant way to do the computations was suggested in comments by @VarunVejalla: Solving $w=\sqrt{z+6}$ gives $z=w^2-6$, i.e. the relation $6\phi(w)= \phi(w^2-6)$. To simplify notation set $w=3+u$. Then $\psi(u)=\phi(3+u)$
is to be expanded around 0 and verifies $6\psi(u)=\phi((3+u)^2-6) = \psi(6u+u^2)$. Inserting $\psi(u)=u + \sum_{n\geq 2} a_n u^n$ yields the identity between Taylor series:

$$ 6u + \sum_{n\geq 2} 6 a_n u^n = (6u+u^2) + \sum_{n\geq 2} a_n (6u +u^2)^n $$
or
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2} a_n ((6u+u^2)^n-6u^n)  = -u^2 $$
Expanding the binomial and identifying coefficients you may solve recursively to get a formula for $a_n$ which only depends upon the $a_k$ with $n/2 \leq k \leq n$. You get $a_1=1$ and then
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{6-6^n} \sum_{k =\lceil n/2 \rceil}^{n-1}
\pmatrix {k \\ n-k} 6^{2k-n} a_k $$
The first terms:
$$ \psi_4(u) = u -\frac{1}{30}u^2 + \frac{1}{525} u^3 - \frac{181}{1354500} u^4. $$
With 12 terms one gets $6 \psi_{12}(\sqrt{6}-3) =  3.365657539743842...
$ correct to 14 digits.

Comment: To add on to this, the coefficients of the Taylor series of $\phi(z)$ can be written somewhat explicitly as $a_n=\frac{1}{6-6^n}\sum_{k=\lceil n/2 \rceil}^{n-1}\binom{k}{n-k}a_k 6^{2k-n}$ for $n \ge 2$, with $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla Thanks for the remark. And nice formula. I suppose that you develloped the version $6\psi(u)=\psi(6u+u^2)$ to obtain this?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. The square roots would have been annoying to deal with.

Comment: @VarunVejalla OK, if you don't mind, I'll add this to my post?

Comment: Sure, feel free to add it in!

Comment: I must have misread your comment last night, but I used that $6\phi(u) = \phi(u^2-6)$, which comes from making the substitution $z = u^2-6$. I don't think the relation you have in your comment is right.

Comment: @VarunVejalla  As I mention it is actually just the translate so that (in my notation) you expand at $u=0$ and not $w=3$.

Answer (score 12):

The following solution is a special case of a general method.

The question asks

> Let $a_ 1=\sqrt{6}$, $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{6+a_n}$. Find
> $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n-3)6^n$.

With $\,q\,$ as a parameter, define the function
$$ F(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \frac{x^n}{f_n}\;\;
 \text{ where }\;\; f_n:= \prod_{k=1}^n (1-q^k) \tag{1} $$
and where $\,|q|\ne1.\,$ Define the constants
$$ L := q/2, \quad \text{ and } \quad K := L^2-L. \tag{2} $$
Also define
$$ a_n := A\left(\frac{x_0}{q^n}\right) \;\;
\text{ where } \;\; A(x) := L - q\, x\, F(x) \tag{3} $$
and where $\,x_0 = A^{-1}(a_0)\,$ depends only on
$\,q\,$ and $\,a_0.\,$

Tthe value of $\,x_0\,$ computed this way does **not**
suffer from floating point rounding problems.

The equation
$$ a_{n+1} = \sqrt{K+a_n} \quad \text{ or } \quad a_{n+1}^2 = K+a_n \tag{4} $$
implies that  the coefficients of $\,F(x)\,$ as polynomials in $\,q\,$ satisfy
$$ c_0 = 1, \quad c_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^n c_{n-k}\,c_k\,
 \frac{f_n}{f_k f_{n-k}}. \tag{5} $$

Note that
$$ F(0) = 1,\; A(0) = L \; \text{ and }\;
 a_n\to L. \tag{6} $$
The approach of $\,a_n\,$ to the limit $\,L\,$ is given by
$$ L - a_n = q \, \frac{x_0}{q^n}
 F\left(\frac{x_0}{q^n} \right)
\approx q\frac{x_0}{q^n}. \tag{7} $$
This implies
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n-L)\,q^n = -q\,x_0. \tag{8} $$

In the case in the question,
$$ q = 6,\; L = 3,\; a_0 = 0,\;
 x_0 \approx 0.56094292329064. \tag{9} $$

In the case from Art of Problem Solving Online,
$$ q = 4,\; L = 2,\; a_0 = 0,\;
 x_0 = \frac{\pi^2}{16},\; F(x) = \frac{\sin(\sqrt{x})^2}x. \tag{10} $$

---

NOTE: About my method.
Some of it is based on [Koenigs function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koenigs_function) but my version is more constructive.
If we have a function $\,T(x)\,$ and define a sequence by
$\,a_{n+1} = T(a_n)\,$ where $\,a_n\to 0\,$
such that $\, a_n \approx c/q^n,\,$ then use the Ansatz
$\, a_n = F(x/q^n)\,$ for some function $\,F\,$ with a power
series expansion in $\,x\,$ with coefficients that depend on $\,q.\,$
The coefficients are uniquely determined by the function $\,T.$
The mode of convergence determines the proper Ansatz. For
example, $\,T(x) := x-x^2\,$ requires a different Ansatz.

NOTE: If $\,q=1\,$ then the convergence $\,a_n\to \frac14\,$ is
much slower and the above analysis does not hold. Instead the one
for $\,T(x) := x-x^2\,$ is needed. Something similar if $\,q=-1\,$
and other roots of unity.

NOTE: I was going to mention chapter 8.3 of *Asymptotic Methods in Analysis*
by de Bruijn which I am familiar with but didn't have the exact page number.

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more detail on the origin of $F(x, q) $? The solution looks deeply mysterious!!

Comment: Just curious, did Ramanujan have anything to do with this technique? Even if he didn't, he would have liked this kind of approach.

Comment: @Somos Please let me ask...How did you invent all this?  I would be glad if you want to say / share.  How did you invent it all?  Does your answer prove that the value of the limit cannot be expressed in $\pi$ ? And also, does your answer prove that the limit cannot be expressed by any "known" constant in mathematics?.. Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps I am overlooking something obvious, but how did you calculate $x_0$ from the given data?

Comment: @MartinR That is a good question! I used numerical methods. Mathematica `FindRoot` based on a finite truncation of the power series $\,F(x).$

Comment: @lonestudent Those are good questions! I used methods that were invented by others over a period of decades to solve similar problems. My guess is that the limit is not expressible by known constants in closed form. No proof of any of this.

Comment: Thanks for response @Somos (+1). You may want to add references for us.

Comment: I would also love a reference for this machinery, if you have one! (+1, ofc)

Comment: Thanks for adding references! This method is explained very well in chapter 8.3 of de Bruijn's "Asymptotic Methods in Analysis" ^_^

Comment: @ Somos Great work! I would appreciate if your solution confirmed the function $b_{\infty}(a_1)$ the approximate form and graph of which I gave in my solution? Could you please comment.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Thanks for asking! I have made many calculations and your function $\,b_\infty(a_1)\,$ is a close approximation. A better one is $\,b_\infty(a_1) = 2247.19(t-9^{0.44966})/(t+47.5757)\,$ where $\,t=(6+a_1)^{0.44966}.$

Answer (score 8):

Here's a proof that $b_n:=(3-a_n)6^n$ converges to a finite limit. This is merely **a proof of existence of a finite limit** (which I don't think is trivial).

It is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3534523/66096) that $a_n$ is strictly increasing and has limit $3$.

Note that
$$3-a_{n+1} = \frac{3-a_n}{3+\sqrt{6+a_n}}$$

hence
$$(3-a_{n+1})6^{n+1} = \frac{6}{3+\sqrt{6+a_n}} (3-a_n)6^n$$

thus

$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = \frac{6}{3+\sqrt{6+a_n}}>1$$

---

Let us show that $\sum_n \ln\Big(\frac{6}{3+\sqrt{6+a_n}}\Big)$ converges.
From $$3-a_{n+1} = \frac{3-a_n}{3+\sqrt{6+a_n}}\leq \frac 13 (3-a_n)$$
one readily finds that $3-a_n = O(\frac 1{3^n})$, hence $a_n = 3 + O(\frac 1{3^n})$, thus
$$\ln\Big(\frac{6}{3+\sqrt{6+a_n}}\Big) 
= \ln\Big(\frac{6}{3+\sqrt{9+O(\frac 1{3^n})}}\Big) 
= \ln(1+O(\frac 1{3^n})) 
= O(\frac 1{3^n})$$
Hence$\sum_n \ln\Big(\frac{6}{3+\sqrt{6+a_n}}\Big)$ converges.

---

Thus $\sum_n \log(\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n})$ converges, hence the sequence $\log b_n$ converges to a finite limit, hence $b_n$ converges as well to some positive real.

Therefore, the sequence $(a_n-3)6^n$ converges to a negative real number.

Comment: I don't know why the downvote, (+1) from me. It's correct, but you have just shown that the limit exists, OP asks to find the limit too.

Comment: I cannot find a flaw, (+1) from me. With $(3-a_n) \le (3-a_1)/3^{n-1}$ and $\ln x \le x-1$ (instead of the big-oh estimates) you might even find a concrete upper bound for the limit.

Comment: @lonestudent Read the first sentence of his proof (the part in bold specifically)

Comment: @lonestudent Before finding the limit of a sequence, it is worth wondering whether it is convergent in the first place...

Comment: Numerical experiments (with PARI/GP) indicate that the limit of $(3-a_n)6^n$ is approximately $3.36565753974384094$. It may well be that this cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, the [inverse symbolic calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=3.36565753974384094&lookup_type=simple) does not recognize that number. – Proving that the limit exists at all is a substantial contribution in my opinion.

Comment: @Martin $$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots}}}=2\cos \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$$ Is it not possible to construct a similar formula for $\sqrt 6$?

Comment: @lonestudent: I am aware of that (and some similar) recursions which have an explicit solution. If I knew how to do the same for sequence given here then I would already have written an answer :)

Comment: @Martin I actually kept the comment short:.  I knew you knew this formula for sure :) Please let me edit my comment.  Why can't the formula finding method used for $\sqrt 2$  work for $\sqrt 6$?  so what makes the $\sqrt 2$ special?  I don't know how to find this formula.  I only know the proof by induction.  in short: does the formula finding method for $\sqrt 2$ work only in "special cases"? Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @lonestudent: The factor $2^{n+1}$ in your example comes from the “half-angle formula” for the cosine. Here we would need a different factor, but there are no equally “simple” formulas for $\cos(x/c)$ for $c \ne 2$, at least none that I know of. I am not saying that it is not possible, just that I don't yet know how.

Comment: @lonestudent. If $a_0=0,\ a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+a_n}$ then $4^{n+1}(2-a_n) \to \pi^2.$

Comment: @Martin Thank you very much.! It was good to learn that.

Comment: @md2perpe Yes :)  I found it in the search result.  It is possible to prove it using the trig formula. Thanks.!!

Comment: @lonestudent. I know it from the other end, by deriving a sequence converging to $\pi$ by bisecting triangles in a circle.

Answer (score 5):

In this answer we consider the sequence $b_n=|3-a_n|6^n$, where $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{6+a_n}$ with initiial condition $a_0\geq0$. We show that $b_n$ is

1. bounded and  monotone increasing if $0\leq a_0<3$ (see \eqref{three}).
2. bounded  and monotone decreasing when $a_0>3$ (see \eqref{twop}).

As a consequence,

3. $b_n(a_0)$ (dependence of initial condition)  is convergent for all $a_0\geq0$:
   $$b_\infty(a_0)=|3-a_0|\prod^\infty_{n=1}\Big(1-\frac{|3-a_n|}{6}\Big)^{-1}$$
4. When $0\leq a_0<3$, $(a_n-3)6^n=-b_n$ converges to a negative number; when $a_0>3$, $(a_n-3)6^n=b_n$ converges to a positive number.

I don't think the limit $b_\infty(a_0)=\lim_nb_n(a_0)$ can be expressed in terms of elementary functions. A numerical estimate (with double precision arithmetic) gives $b_\infty(0)\approx3.3657$.

---

The map $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ defined by
$$ f(x)=\sqrt{6+x}$$
is a contraction: First notice that $f(x)\geq\sqrt{6}$ for all $x\in[0,\infty$, and
\begin{align}
f(x)-f(y)=\frac{y-x}{\sqrt{6+x}+\sqrt{6+y}}\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
Then,
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\frac{1}{2\sqrt{6}}|x-y|
$$
and so,  for any $a_0\geq0$,  $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ converges to a fixed  point $x=f(x)$ with $x\geq0$, which in this case is  $x=3$.

---

Further analysis of the map $f$ shows that

1. If $3<a_0$, then $3<a_n<a_{n-1}$ for all $n\geq1$
2. If $0\leq a_0<3$, then $a_{n-1}<a_n<3$ for all $n\geq1$.

---

We now study the speed of convergence of the sequence $a_n$. Let $d_n=|3-a_n|=|f(3)-f(a_{n-1})|$. It follows from \eqref{one} that
$$d_n=\frac{d_{n-1}}{3+a_n}$$
If $0\leq a_0<3$, then
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{6}d_{n-1}<d_n=\frac{d_{n-1}}{3+a_n}=\frac{d_{n-1}}{6-d_n}\tag{2}\label{two}
\end{align}
As $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}3$, we have that
$\frac{d_{n+1}}{d_n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{6}$;
consequently $\sqrt[n]{d_n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{6}$.
This alone however, does not provide convergence of $b_n=(6\sqrt[n]{d_n})^n$.

---

Now we prove that the sequence $b_n$ indeed converges. From \eqref{two} we have that
\begin{align}
b_{n-1}=6^{n-1}d_{n-1}< 6^nd_n=b_n=\frac{6^{n-1}d_{n-1}}{1-\tfrac{d_n}{6}}=\frac{b_{n-1}}{1-\tfrac{d_n}{6}}\tag{3}\label{three}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{d_{n-1}}{6}<d_n\leq\frac{d_{n-1}}{3+a_0}\leq \frac{d_0}{(3+a_0)^{n-1}}\tag{4}\label{four}
\end{align}
Putting this together, we obtain
\begin{align}
b_n=b_0\prod^n_{k=1}\frac{b_k}{b_{k-1}}=b_0\prod^n_{k=1}\Big(1-\tfrac{d_k}{6}\Big)^{-1}\tag{5}\label{five}
\end{align}
From \eqref{four} we have that  $\sum^\infty_{k=1}d_k<\infty$; from
$$\prod^n_{k=1}\Big(1-\tfrac{d_k}{6}\Big)\leq \exp\Big(-\frac{1}{6}\sum^n_{k=1}d_k\Big)$$
we conclude that $b_n$ converges, and that
\begin{align}
b_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} b_0\prod^\infty_{k=1}\big(1-\tfrac{d_k}{6}\big)^{-1}\tag{6}\label{6}
\end{align}

---

**Remarks:**

1. An interesting observation is that when $a_0>3$, convergence of $b_n$ is much easier to check, for in this case,  the inequalities in \eqref{two} are reverse, that is
   \begin{align}
   \frac{d_{n-1}}{6+d_n}=\frac{d_{n-1}}{3+a_n}=d_n<\frac{1}{6}d_{n-1}\tag{2'}\label{twop}
   \end{align}
   This implies  $ b_n<b_{n-1}$ and convergence follows immediately. This can be explained in part to the fact that $f'(x)=\big(2\sqrt{6+x}\big)^{-1}$ is a decreasing function, and so $f'(y)<f'(x)$ whenever $x<3<y$. So convergence tens to be faster to the right of $3$.
2. Notice that the limit of the  sequence $b_n$ depends on the initial condition $a_0$. For $a_0=0$, simple numerical implementation gives $\lim_nb_n\approx 3.3657$; for $a_0=6$, $\lim_nb_n\approx 2.7426$

Answer (score 1):

Ths approach shows that the results in question emerge quite naturally from the standard fixed-points-stability analysis of the evolution equation. Also the dependence of the limit of $b_n = (a_n -3)6^n$  from the inital value $a_1$ is discussed.

Following the common procedure to analyse the evolution equation

$$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{6+a_{n}}\tag{1}$$

we fist look for fixed points. These follow from the equation $0 = a^2-a-6$ to be $a = 3$ and $a=-2$.

Ruling out the negative solution we study the stabilty letting

$$a_{n} = 3 +\delta_{n}\tag{2}$$

where $|\delta_{n}| << 3$.

Inserting into $(1)$ gives

$$\begin{align}
& 3 +\delta_{n+1} = \sqrt{6+3+\delta_{n}}=\sqrt{9+\delta_{n}}\\&=3\left( \sqrt{1+\frac{\delta_{n}}{9}}\right)\simeq 3\left( 1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\delta_{n}}{9}\right)=3 +\frac{1}{6} \delta_{n}\end{align} $$

whence follows

$$\delta_{n+1} \simeq \frac{1}{6} \delta_{n}\tag{3}$$

The solution $\delta_{n}=\frac{c}{6^n}$ of $(3)$ with some constant $c$ shows that the fixed point $a_{\infty}=3$ is stable and from $(2)$ we find

$$a_{n} \simeq 3 + \frac{c}{6^n}\tag{4}$$

This in turn means that

$$b_{n} := \left(a_{n} - 3 \right)6^n \simeq c\tag{5}$$

So that the limit in question is the constant $c$. For $0 \lt a_{1} \lt 3$ the constant $c$ is negative, for $a_{1} \gt 3$ it is positive. In the actual case we have $a_{1} = \sqrt{6} \lt 3$, and the limit is numerically

$$b_{\infty} \simeq -3.36571\tag{6}$$.

**Limit as a function of the initial value**

Here is a plot showing the dependence of the limit $b_{\infty}$ on the initial value $a_{1}$ for $-6 \le a_{1} <10$

[image]

Some special values of the limit are: $b_{\infty}(-6) = -121.164$, $b_{\infty}(0) = -20.1939$, and $b_{\infty}(3) = 0$

The limit function is well approximated by

$$b_{\infty}(a_1)=45.1116 (a_1+6)^{0.44966}-121.164\tag{7}$$

Comment: You switch from “approximate/asymptotic equality” ($\simeq$) to equality at various places, the equations (3) and (4) do surely not hold as written.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I thought is was clear what is meant from the context.

Comment: Your solution is still a bit unclear to me. I assume that (3) means $\lim_{n\to \infty} \delta_{n+1}/\delta_{n} = 1/6$. But that alone does not imply the convergence of $6^n \delta_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Found a possible numerical approach compatible with Gabriel Romon above. Calculate $a_n$ for $n=0,1,2,...,10$.

Define $q_n=(3-a_n)6^{n}$.

Then, $\ln(1-\frac{q_n}{q_{n+1}})$ can be fitted with a straight line as a function of $n$  having $r^2=0.9983$.

If the argument of the natural logarithm here is taken to be the ratio of the first derivative to the function itself, this implies $q(n)$ is a double exponential.

To Wit:

$$q_n=(3-a_n)6^n \approx q(n)= c_1e^{(\frac{e^b}{m}e^{mn})}$$

where m and b are the slope and intercept respectively for the aforementioned line, and $c_1$ is a constant.

In my modeling, m=-1.8368, b = -0.4174.

This suggest $c_1$ is the limit in question and fitting $q(n)$ against the $q_n$ will yield $c_1$, approximating the desired result, however so far my attempts give a value of about 4.27.

Answer (score 0):

With $b_n:=(a_n-3)6^{n}$ we rewrite

$$6^{-n-1}b_{n+1}+3=\sqrt{6+6^{-n}b_n+3}$$

and

$$b_{n+1}=6^{n+1}\left(\sqrt{9+6^{-n}b_n}-3\right)=\frac{6b_n}{\sqrt{9+6^{-n}b_n}+3},$$

with $b_1=6(\sqrt 6-3)$. This proves that if $b_n$ converges, it converges to a negative value. As the denominator is asymptotic to $a+6^{-n}c$, it should be possible to find an upper bound and prove convergence.

Comment: Is it possible to find a general formula for $a_n?$  I think on it.  Is it possible to do this using only algebra?  Do you think it is worth trying to looking for a general formula?

Comment: @lonestudent: I don't believe so.