# Limit of $f_{n+1} = \sqrt{12 + f_n}$ with proof by contradiction

Tags: calculus, limits, recurrence-relations

Consider the following recursive sequence:

$$
\begin{cases}
f_{0}=\sqrt{12}\\
f_{n+1}=\sqrt{12 + f_{n}}
\end{cases}
$$

for $n \geq 0$. How can I prove that this sequence is bounded above by $4$ and
thus its limit is also $4$?

Comment: Try proving that it's increasing and bounded above. That should be enough..

Comment: Proving it's bounded is not enough to prove it converges: the sequence $\;(-1)^n$  is bounded.

Comment: Read carefully: I wrote "increasing and bounded". And that's enough for convergence..

Comment: I don't know what contradiction you're looking for. I edited your title and tags, but I left the contradiction part because you had put it there.

Comment: Special case of [$\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\cdots}}}$, or the limit of the sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+x_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq)

Answer (score 7):

First, being bounded above by $4$ neither guarantees convergence nor, if we knew it converges, that it converges to $4$.

It's easier to show that this converges and then to show that it converges to $4$. To show that it converges, you want to

1. Show that $f_n$ is increasing.

   You can do this directly through induction. It's pretty straightforward.
2. Show that $f_n$ is bounded above.

   You will have a much easier time by choosing a clever, lenient upper bound. I recommend showing that $f_n < 1 + 2\sqrt{12}$. This number might seem magical. But notice that in the inductive step, we would argue like this:

   $$ f_n = \sqrt{12 + f_{n-1}} \leq \sqrt{12 + 2\sqrt{12} + 1} = 1 + \sqrt 12 \lt 1 + 2\sqrt {12}.$$

   This choice simplified that inductive argument quite a bit over what it could have been.

Now that you know it converges, you can use the standard argument. Call $L$ the limit. Then we must have $L = \sqrt{12 + L}$. Simplifying, factoring, and throwing out the negative limit shows the actual limit is $4$. $\diamondsuit$

Comment: Solid answer ... so a +1.  But, just curious here .... Why is the use of  $f_n\le 4$, in the inductive step, to conclude that $f_{n+1}\le 4$ viewed as difficult?

Comment: @Dr.MV You know, that's interesting. I thought when I was first writing this down that using $4$ directly was nontrivial. But it's rather easy. Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

By induction  you can prove that the sequence is monoton (strictly) increasing $${ f }_{ 1 }^{ 2 }=12+{ f }_{ 0 }=12+\sqrt { 12 } =12+2\sqrt { 3 } \\ { f }_{ 2 }^{ 2 }=12+12+2\sqrt { 3 } =24+2\sqrt { 3 } \\ { f }_{ 1 }<{ f }_{ 2 }\\ { f }_{ n }<{ f }_{ n+1 }$$

Let say $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { f }_{ n } } =f$
then $${ f }^{ 2 }-f-12=0$$ $$\left( f-4 \right) \left( f+3 \right) =0$$
so monoton increasing and bounded  above sequence has limit,and limit is $4$

Comment: where did you proof that it's upper-bounded?

Comment: it is a hint,i didn't prove

Comment: $f_0 = \sqrt{12}$, not $12$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

To prove a recursive sequence is convergent, one strategy is to prove it is non-decreasing and bounded from above, or its non-increasing and bounded from below.

If the sequence is defined with a function $g$,: $f_{n+1}=g(f_n)$, it is  non-decreasing if the graph of $g$ is *above*  the line $y=x$ on an interval $I$ and all $f_n$ belong to $I$. If the interval $I$ is bounded from above, the sequence will also be bounded from above, hence it will converge.

Furthermore, if $g$ is continuous, the limit $\ell$ will satisfy the equation $\; \ell=g(\ell)$, in other words, the limit will be a fixed point of $g$. If there is only one fixed point, it will be the limit. If there are several fixed  points, you will have to decide (and prove) which fixed point is the limit.