# Prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2}}}=2$

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2}}}=2$

How to evaluate this limit?

Comment: Hint: show that the sequence is monotonic and bounded from above. It will follow that the limit exists. Then use properties of limits to show it must be $2$.

Comment: look at it as the sequence of numbers $\{x_n\}$ where $x_1 = \sqrt{2}$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+x_n}$. Then do it as Wojowu suggests

Comment: possible duplicate of [$\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c+\cdots}}}$, or the limit of the sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{c+x_n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq)

Answer (score 4):

The standard idea would be to define a sequence $a_n$ as follows:
$a_0=\sqrt{2}$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}$ for all $n \ge 0$.
Then you want to evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$.
One way to prove convergence is to prove that $a_n$ is bounded above and mononotically increasing. Both of them should not be too hard.
Then, if you know that it converges to the limit $L$ you find $L=\sqrt{2+L}$ and then can solve for $L$.
Can you complete this proof on your own?

Answer (score 3):

It is the limit of the sequence defined by $u_0=0$  and $\;u_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+u_n}$. As the function $f(x)=\sqrt{2+x}$, is continuous the limit $\ell$ is a nonnegative fixed point of the function, i.e. is satisfies the equation:
$$\ell=\sqrt{\ell+2}\iff \ell^2-\ell-2=0\enspace\text{and}\enspace \ell\ge 0 $$
Now this equation has two roots, $2$ and$-1$. You eliminate the negative root.

As noticed by @Thomas Andrews, this supposes you've proved there *is* a limit first. As the function maps $[-2,2]$ to $[0,2]$, and $f(x)>x$ on this interval, we have an increasing, bounded from above sequence, which therefore converges to a limit.

Comment: The limit, *if it exists,* is that value.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Of course, but the question, as formulated by the O.P., was not about how to prove the sequence  converges. I'll add this remark.

Comment: "How to evaluate this limit" does not imply "if this limit exists," so, no, your are wrong.

Comment: For me, it meant that he/she had solved the question of the existence of the limit. Otherwise the question would have been something like ‘ how to show there's a limit’. At least that's the way I'd formulate it.