# Limit of a sequence given by $x_n = \sqrt{3 + x_{n-1}}$ as n approaches infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, nested-radicals

Let $x_1 = 1$ and for $n \ge2, x_n = \sqrt{3 + x_{n-1}}$, I just want to know how to determine the limit.

Comment: This post seems related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq And you can find several related questions among the posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/115501).

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** prove that your sequence is increasing and bounded, hence converging to its supremum, then notice that there is only one real number $r$ such that $r=\sqrt{r+3}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you know the Banach fixed-point theorem, then $f(x)=\sqrt{3+x}$ has Lipschitz constant $1/4$ on $[1,\infty)$.