# Show the sequence $\{{\sqrt{5}}~,{\sqrt{5+{\sqrt5}}}~,\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}~,...\}$ converges and find its limit.

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-verification, nested-radicals

Show the sequence $\bigg\{{\sqrt{5}}~,{\sqrt{5+{\sqrt5}}}~,\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}~,...\bigg\}$ converges and find its limit.

**Attempt :**

Let $a_{1}=\sqrt{5}$ and $a_{n+1}={\sqrt{5+a_{n}}}$ for $n=2,3,...$

Now we apply the induction to prove the sequence$(a_{n})$ is increasing , bounded above by $3.$

**$(a_{n})$ is increasing $:$**

Note first that $a_{n}\ge0$ for each $n\in{\bf N}$.

As $n=1$, one has $a_{1}^{2}=5<5+\sqrt 5=a_{2}^{2}\Longrightarrow |a_{1}|<|a_{2}|\Longrightarrow a_{1}<a_{2}$ .

Now assume $a_{n-1}<a_{n}$ for some $n\in\bf N$ .

Then $a_{n}^{2}=5+a_{n-1}<5+a_{n}=a_{n+1}^{2}\Longrightarrow |a_{n}|<|a_{n+1}|\Longrightarrow a_{n}<a_{n+1}$ .

**$(a_{n})$ is bounded above by 3 $:$**

As the same manner , we have $a_{1}=\sqrt 5<\sqrt 9=3$ for $n=1$.

Suppose the process holds for some integer $n>0,$ that is , $a_{n}<3$ for some $n\in\bf N$ .

Whence , $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{5+a_{n}}<\sqrt{5+3}<\sqrt9=3 .$

Therefore, we see on account of the [monotonic sequence Theorem](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-monotonic-sequence-theorem-for-convergence) that $(a_{n})$ is convergent .

**Limit of $(a_{n}):$**

Take $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}=L$ for some $L\ge0$ since $a_{n}$ is non-negative for all $n\in\bf N$.

Thus , $\sqrt{5+L}=\sqrt{5+\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n-1}}\color{red}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{5+a_{n-1}}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}=L$ , keep in mind that the red equality holds by $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous .

Then , one has $L^{2}-L-5=0\Longrightarrow L=\displaystyle\frac{1+\sqrt{21}}{2}$ since $L$ is non-negative .

Can anyone check my proof for validity if you have the time , otherwise ignore this, that is okay . Any comment or valuable suggestion I will be grateful .

Comment: It goes through.

Comment: amWhy has changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, @GNUSupporter, for the explanation.  I started writing a comment to explain why; but saw your comment, more thorough than mine.  Appreciate it!

Comment: Please check for duplicates before asking https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq

Comment: Really nice job.  It is good.  You did every step nicely.

Comment: Now replace 5 by c and see if everything carries through.

Comment: It's perfect. BTW: If you replace $5$ with $c>0,$ so $a_{n+1}^2=c+a_n$ and $a_1=\sqrt c\; $you can show the sequence is increasing and bounded by showing that $0<a_n<L\implies 0<a_n<a_{n+1}<L,$  where $L>0$ and $L^2-L-c=0$.