# Real numbers arbitrary closeness (iterated fraction)

Tags: fractional-iteration

I was playing with some iterated functions/fractions when I stumbled across this one
$$\frac{1+\frac{1+\frac{1+...}{1-...}}{1-\frac{1+...}{1-...}}}{1-\frac{1+\frac{1+...}{1-...}}{1-\frac{1+...}{1-...}}}$$
which I found to be equal $i$.
Am I correct?
And if so, does it mean real numbers are not closed under arbitrary basic arithmetic (assuming there is no zero-division somewhere in it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As any field, the real numbers are definately closed under basic arithmetic operations. Namely for any two reals $x$ and $y$, $x+y$, $x-y$, $x\cdot y$ and, given that $y\neq 0$, $\frac{x}{y}$, are real numbers.

The reals are also complete, and from this it follows that any sequence of reals that converges in the complex numbers must converge to a real number. So I don't see how 
$$
a_{n+1}=\frac{1+a_n}{1-a_n}
$$
can converge to $i$.

Comment: I'm not sure your $a_n$ is the same as my fraction since you must have $a_0$ which I don't have. And if I'm wrong, can anybody please tell me what my expression equals?

Comment: Yeah I would need to know what $a_0$ is. To me that expression the way you've written it is not well defined.

Comment: Since it's infinite I thought I can substitute $x=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$, and that's how I got $i$ (and $-i$ ).

Comment: You need to define clearly what the expression is. If it's the limit of a sequence then you need to say what $a_0$ is. As I've said for any real $a_0$ the limit of the sequence if it exists must be real too. If however $a_0=i$ or $a_0=-i$ then indeed the limit would be $i$ and $-i$ respectively.

Comment: I thought I can find its value like finding the value of $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+...}}}$ by having $x=\sqrt{1+x}$ and getting $x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: @GetMathed again you have to fix a valued for $a_0$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq). For example the sequence in your comment seems to converge only for certain initial values.