# A sequence is defined by $x_1=1$, $x_{n+1}= \sqrt{8+x_n}$. Prove each term of the sequence after the first is greater than the preceding term.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried to use mathematical induction, but letting $n=k$ and $n=k+1$ is getting nowhere. I also tried squaring both sides to get rid of the square root but that doesn't seem to help either. Need some hints...

After reading some hints,
For $n=k$, assume $x_k > x_{k-1}$

$\sqrt{8+x_{k-1}} > \sqrt{8+x_{k-2}}$

Prove it is true for $k+1$,

$x_k = \sqrt{8+x_{k-1}}$

Squaring both sides,

$8+x_k > 8+x_{k-1}$

$x_k > x_{k-1}$

Since it is true for $n=k+1$, it is also true for $n=k$.

Seems right?

Comment: Please show your previous attempts and use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks and done. Looks right?

Comment: If you try to prove the sequence converges, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115501/sqrtc-sqrtc-sqrtc-cdots-or-the-limit-of-the-sequence-x-n1-sq?noredirect=1&lq=1) is the general solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You can try induction. If you suppose that $x_{n}>x_{n-1}$, then

$$8+x_n>8+x_{n-1}\to \sqrt{8+x_{n}}>\sqrt{8+x_{n-1}}.$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edit. Seems right?

Comment: @SamuelWong: No, it is not. Take a look at my hint. What is the meaning of the last inequality?

Comment: Your last inequality actually implies $x_n$ is greater than its preceding term which is what we're asked to prove?

Comment: @SamuelWong: Yep!

Comment: @SamuelWong: If one of the answers satisfy you, could you please, choose one of them (pressing the check mark)? In doing this, you avoid this question pop up many times in the list of question.

Answer (score 1):

$$n=1: \;\; x_n = x_1 =1<3=\sqrt{8+1}=\sqrt{8+x_n}=x_{n+1}$$
S.t. it holds for $n$.
$$\begin{aligned}n \mapsto n+1: \;\;\;& x_{n+1} \;<\; x_{n+2} \\[5mm] \iff\;\;& x_{n+1} < \sqrt{8 + x_{n+1}} \\[5mm] \iff\;\;& \sqrt{8+x_n} \;<\; \sqrt{8+\sqrt{8+x_n}}\\[5mm] \iff\;\;& 8 + x_n \;<\; 8 + \sqrt{8 + x_n} \\[5mm] \iff\;\;& x_n \;<\; \sqrt{8+x_n} \;\; \iff \;\; x_n \;<\;x_{n+1}\end{aligned} $$
S.t. it is also true for $n+1$, therefore completing the proof by induction.