# Show that $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2...}}}$ converges to 2

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, nested-radicals

Consider the sequence defined by
$a_1 = \sqrt{2}$, $a_2 = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}$, so that in general, $a_n = \sqrt{2 + a_{n - 1}}$ for $n > 1$.
I know 2 is an upper bound of this sequence (I proved this by induction). Is there a way to show that this sequence converges to 2? What I think is that the key step is to prove 2 is the least upper bound of this sequence. But how?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849274/the-convergence-of-sqrt-2-sqrt-2-sqrt-2-ldots

Comment: $a_n$ converges to $2$ because it's monotone increasing and bounded by $2$. With induction you get $\sqrt{2+a_{n+1}} = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+a_n}} \leq \sqrt{2+2} = 2$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $ x = \sqrt {2 + \sqrt {2 + \sqrt {2 + \cdots}}} $. Then, note that $$ x^2 = 2 + \sqrt {2 + \sqrt {2 + \cdots}} = 2 + x \implies x^2 - x - 2 = 0. $$Note that the two solutions to this equation are $x=2$ and $x=-1$, but since this square root cannot be negative, it must be $2$.

Comment: You haven't proven convergence.

Comment: If it didn't converge, I wouldn't get a valid solution.

Comment: Really? Take the sequence $a_0 = 1, a_{n+1} = 2 a_n$. Then if the limit exists, it must satisfy $x = 2x$, and therefore $x = 0$. Do you think the sequence converges to 0?

Comment: You have a point. For such a proof, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61048/definition-of-convergence-of-a-nested-radical-sqrta-1-sqrta-2-sqrta-3).

Comment: It's much simpler here, the sequence is increasing and bounded above by 2. Therefore it converges. The limit does satisfy $x^2 = x+2$, and the reason it's not $-1$ is because the sequence is increasing and starts at a positive number.

Comment: Thanks Ahaan. But I still cannot see that the limit x is $\sqrt{x+2}$.

Comment: Write before you posted, I was about to add [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11945/limit-of-the-nested-radical-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-cdots), which is slightly more appropriate. Your reason about the radical not being $-1$ is identical to mine.

Comment: Is there a way to show that 2 is the greatest upper bound and then use the monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: @Yihan Note that $x^2-2$ is the same nested radical, since it's infinite.

Comment: Just curious, why was this downvoted?

Comment: @AhaanRungta Did I? I might press the wrong button. Sorry

Comment: Your answer is obvious, but I don't think it answers the question.

Answer (score 9):

Set $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}$ and $a_0= \sqrt{2}$. We want to calculate
 the limit of $a_n$.

First, $0<a_n<2$ implies that $0<a_{n+1} <\sqrt{2+2} =2$ and $0<a_0<2$
 then $a_n<2$ for any integer $n\geq 0$.

Second, we have $a_{n+1}^2 -a_n^2= 2+a_n-a_n^2 =(2-a_n)(1+a_n)>0$ then
 $a_n$ is increasing.

Since $a_n$ is increasing and bounded from above it converges to
 $a\in[0,2]$ and then $a=\sqrt{2+a}$ and clearly we have $a=2$.

Comment: To rigorously justify the last step of finding the limit, use the fact that subsequence of a sequence converges to the same limit as the original, so $\lim a_{n+1} = \lim a_n = a$; then by the Algebraic Limit Theorem, we can manipulate the limits to simplify: $(\lim (a_{n+1}))^2 = a^2  = \lim (a_{n+1})^2 = \lim (2 + a_n) = 2 + \lim a_n = 2+a$.