# The convergence of $\sqrt {2+\sqrt {2+\sqrt {2+\ldots}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, nested-radicals

I would like to know if this sequence converges $\sqrt {2+\sqrt {2+\sqrt {2+\ldots}}}$.

I know this sequence is increasing monotone, but I couldn't prove it's bounded.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a sequence ? I don't think so ! May be you want to calculate the value of this number. Am I right ?

Comment: Or do you mean the following sequence : $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}.\ldots$

Comment: @Debashish the sequence is $a_1=\sqrt 2, a_2=\sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}$,etc.

Comment: @Debashish exactly

Comment: @Debashish It's not uncommon for analysts not to be clear in what they write. The sequence at hand is the one defined by $x_1=\sqrt 2$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+x_n}$.

Comment: I'm assuming the sequence is $a_n=\sqrt {2+a_{n-1}}$

Comment: @GitGud you don't need the internal square root in your definition.

Comment: @GitGud .. Ya thats true.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @GitGud I made that mistake in my answer before I straightened it out ...

Comment: @Aryabhata I disagree with marking these questions as duplicates. Special cases often allow for much neater proofs.

Comment: @user1729PhD: I would like to refer you to: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/coping-with-abstract-duplicate-questions and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions. If the asker is looking for a different answer than those that appear in the generalized question, they can always say so in the question, and a closure will not happen.

Comment: @Aryabhata I am aware of those threads, but I do not think that they are applicable here. [Jeff Atwood](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1760/10513) interprets the sentiment as "old-timers are tired of answering what is essentially the same question in millions of tiny different varations", but I do not think that this is necessarilly applicable here. It is a much reduced question, not a little reduced question. These threads are more for "find the $\gcd$ of $36$ and $15$" vs. "find the $\gcd$ of $100$ and $6$", no?.

Comment: @user1729PhD: I disagree. Where do you draw the line? For instance, who knows, one might find an extremely interesting graph theory proof of $\text{gcd}(100, 6) = 2$. Why close that question? I am repeating myself, but if someone is looking for an answer not given already, they can specifically mention that, and the question will not be closed.

Answer (score 13):

Agreeing with what the others have said, I would like to add that there is in fact a simple explicit formula for the terms of this sequence:

$$
\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \cdots + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\,}\,}\,}\,}\
=\
2\cos\left(\vphantom{\Large A}\pi \over 2^{n + 1}\right)
$$

where the square root sign appears $n$-times. In particular, the sequence clearly converges to $2$.

*Proof*:

For $n=1$, the claim is true, since $\cos(\pi/4)=\sqrt{2}/2$. By the half-angle formula $$2\cos(x/2)=\sqrt{2+2\cos(x)}$$
Therefore
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}=\sqrt{2+2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$
where in the left square root expressions there are $n$ square roots and in the first equality we have used the induction hypothesis that the claim holds for $n-1$.

(From my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649968/proof-of-an-equality-involving-cosine/649972#649972) question.)

Comment: Nice one.${{}}$

Answer (score 10):

Suppose $x\lt 2$

Consider $y=\sqrt {2+x}$ so that $y^2=2+x\lt4$ and $y$ being positive we have $y\lt 2$

That ought to enable you to prove a bound.

Comment: What's your $x$? if your $x$ is equal to $\sqrt {2+\sqrt {2+\sqrt {2+\ldots}}}$, then why you're assuming $x\lt 2$?

Comment: @user42912 If $x_1=\sqrt 2$ and $x_n=\sqrt {2+x_{n-1}}$ for $n\gt 1$ it is a simple induction to show that $x_n\lt 2$ using this method. You just need to start with $\sqrt 2 \lt 2$.

Comment: Thank you, maybe it should be interesting to add this commentary to your answer just for clarify the future users.

Answer (score 3):

Let $l=\sqrt {2+\sqrt {2+\sqrt {2+\ldots}}}$, then $l=\sqrt {2+l}$.

From this we have $l^2-l-2=0$

Can you solve it from here? It has to be bounded if there's a finite solution in the limit as $n\to\infty$ and the sequence is monotone.

Comment: you said "It has to be bounded if there's a finite solution and is monotone." why?

Comment: Sorry, edited it for clarity, I shouldn't be doing math at 2:30am.

Comment: I don't get hows this answers the question (even partially). The OP wants to prove the sequence is bounded. How does your answer help?

Answer (score 2):

As written it's not clear this is a sequence at all but I'm assuming your sequence is

$\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}$, $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2+ \sqrt{2}}}$, $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2+ \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}$, $\sqrt {2+\sqrt {2+\sqrt {2+ \sqrt{2 +\ldots}}}}$.

Then it should be obvious that each entry in the sequence is positive and the sequence increases each time.

Given this the final entry in the infinite sequence would be $x = \sqrt{2 + x}$ which we can easily solve.

$$\begin{align}
x &= \sqrt{2+x} \\
x^2 &= 2 + x\\
x^2 - x -2 &= 0\\
x &= \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{1+8}}{2} \\
x &= \dfrac{4}{2} = 2
\end{align}$$

The sequence has a lower bound of $\sqrt{2}$ and an upper bound of $2$ increasing monotonically.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n = \underbrace{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2 + \ldots + \sqrt{2}}}}_{n\;\text{terms}}$ and $\epsilon_n = 2-a_n$. It is clear 
$$a_1 = \sqrt{2} \quad\implies\quad \epsilon_1 = 2-\sqrt{2} \in(0,1).$$
Notice
$$\epsilon_{n+1} = 2 - \sqrt{2+a_n} = 2 - \sqrt{4-\epsilon_n}
= \frac{\epsilon_n}{2 + \sqrt{4-\epsilon_n}}
\quad\implies\quad \epsilon_{n+1} \in \left(0,\frac{\epsilon_n}{2}\right)
$$
We find 
$\displaystyle\;|\epsilon_n| < \frac{\epsilon_1}{2^{n-1}} < \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}
\to 0\;$ as $n \to \infty$. As a result, $\;a_n \to 2\;$ as $\;n \to \infty$.