# Finding $f’(x)$ - possible answer but need help

Tags: functions, implicit-differentiation

Question: If $f(x) = \cfrac{x}{x + \cfrac{x}{x + \cfrac{x}{x + \vdots}}}$, find $f'(x)$.

Possible Answer:

[image: derivative_of_continued_fraction_solution_attempt]

After searching all over the place I’ve given up and resorted to posting this, I know this is a very simple problem for most of you on here but I was wondering if you could check my answer- found this question somewhere on this website yet they didn’t post the answer.

Thanks

George

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we have that
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{x}{x+f(x)}
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
f'(x) = \frac{x+f(x)-x-xf'(x)}{(x+f(x))^2} \ \ \implies f'(x)\left(1+\frac{x}{(x+f(x))^2} \right) = \frac{f(x)}{(x+f(x))^2}.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
f'(x)=\frac{f(x)}{(x+f(x))^2+x}.
\end{align}

**Edit:** Observe that
\begin{align}
f'(x) =&\ \frac{f(x)}{x^2+2xf(x)+f(x)^2+x} = \frac{f(x)}{x^2+xf(x)+2x} = \frac{f(x)+x-x}{x^2+xf(x)+2x}\\
 =&\ \frac{1-\frac{x}{x+f(x)}}{x\frac{x+f(x)}{x+f(x)}+2\frac{x}{x+f(x)}} = \frac{1-f(x)}{x+2f(x)}.
\end{align}

Comment: What did I do wrong if this is correct? Thanks for answering

Comment: I don't think you did anything work.

Comment: Is this incorrect https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtILS.jpg

Comment: Since both answers agree, then I believe you are correct.

Comment: Thank you, amazing explanation/proof, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a somewhat different answer.  Starting from $$\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{x}{x+f(x)}
\end{align}$$
we have $$xf(x)+f^2(x)=x\\
xf'(x)+f(x)+2f(x)f'(x)=1\implies\\
f'(x)=\frac{1-f(x)}{x+2f(x)}$$

If this solution and Jacky Chong's are both correct (and his certainly looks good to me) we ought to be able to equate them and solve for $f(x).$

**EDIT** As pointed out in KingW3's answer, instead of equating the derivatives, it's easier to just just solve $$f^2(x)+xf(x)-x=0$$ for $f(x)$ in terms of $x$.  This gives $$f(x)=\frac{-x\pm\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2}$$  From the well-known continued fraction for the [golden section](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985996/continued-fraction-of-the-golden-ratio), we know that $$f(1)=\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{2},$$ so we must pick the plus sign, and $$\boxed{f(x)=\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2}}$$

Comment: The OP posted their work, and this was their answer...

Comment: That is what I got as shown in the links I provided, thanks for the response!

Comment: @GeorgeCooper I couldn't read the link you provided.

Comment: Oh thanks for telling me :)

Comment: @saulspatz question:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e9cPQYzPuIKB5J7myOwF37CY1VUnj9hh.                                        answer: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16sIvBwzhbeyDZX9iycNcMzoe3hu_IAva

Answer (score -1):

From $xf(x) +f^2(x)=x$ putting $t=f(x)$ we get a quadratic in $t$ and $t_{1,2}=\frac{-x\pm\sqrt{x^2-4x}}2$. Since you have two different functions you get two different derivatives depending on what $f(x)$ you choose. In this particular case $f(x)$ is not uniquely defined so finding it's derivative is impossible.

Comment: I don't think so.  The continued fraction has a unique value.  You've introduced an extraneous solution.  Besides, I don't get the same solutions as you do.  I have $$\frac{-x\pm\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2}$$

Comment: @saulspatz Yeah I've made a typo on the minus sign, anyway how do you explain that I've introduced an extraneous solution?

Comment: Maybe "introduced" is the wrong term.  I just meant that all we know is that $f$ satisfies this equation; we don't know that it's the only function that satisfies the equation.  Therefore, we know that $f$ occurs among the solutions to the quadratic, but  we have to use other information to decide which it is.  I did this in an edit to my solution; please look there to see why we must pick the + sign.