# How do I prove that this recursive sequence converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_1=\sqrt2$ and let $a_n=\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$ for $n \ge 2$. How do I prove that this sequence converges?

Comment: Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to type with $\LaTeX$ and MathJax on this site so you can type things like $a_n = \sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$

Comment: It it converges to $L$, which natural relationship is "fulfilled" by $L$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't know someone else had already asked this question.

Comment: You might also check the question [linked to the one suggested as a duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/115501). For example. You can finds several posts specifically about $c=2$, like [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849274/the-convergence-of-sqrt-2-sqrt-2-sqrt-2-ldots).

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$a_n=\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}\le\sqrt{2+a_n}=a_{n+1}$$

$$a_n\le 2\iff \sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}\le\sqrt{2+2}=2$$

Can you see now how to prove by induction th above?